# How to loop over the lines of a file?

Tags: shell, control-flow

Say I have this file:

```
hello
world
hello world
```

This program

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat $1); do
    echo "tester: $i"
done
```

outputs

```
tester: hello
tester: world
tester: hello
tester: world
```

I'd like to have the `for` iterate over each line individually ignoring whitespaces though, i.e. the last two lines should be replaced by

```
tester: hello world
```

Using quotes `for i in "$(cat $1)";` results in `i` being assigned the whole file at once. What should I change?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

(9 years later:)
Both provided answers would fail on files without a newline at the end, this will effectively skip the last line, produce no errors, would lead to disaster (learned hard way:).

The best concise solution I found so far that "Just Works" (in both bash and sh):

```
while IFS='' read -r LINE || [ -n "${LINE}" ]; do
    echo "processing line: ${LINE}"
done < /path/to/input/file.txt
```

For more in-depth discussion see this StackOverflow discussion: [How to use "while read" (Bash) to read the last line in a file if there’s no newline at the end of the file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165135/how-to-use-while-read-bash-to-read-the-last-line-in-a-file-if-theres-no-new)

Beware: this approach adds an additional newline to the last line if there is none already.

Comment: files with characters after the last newline are not text files, and those characters don't constitute a line. In many cases those bogus characters are better left ignored or removed, though there are cases where you may want to treat it as a extra line, so it's good you show how.

Comment: Note that files with NUL characters in them are also not text files, and except in zsh that loop would also *fail* if the intention was to keep them as if they were allowed in text files.

Answer (score 98):

With `for` and [IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16192/what-is-ifs-in-context-of-for-looping):

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'       # make newlines the only separator
set -f          # disable globbing
for i in $(cat < "$1"); do
  echo "tester: $i"
done
```

Note however that it will skip empty lines as *newline* being an IFS-white-space character, sequences of it count as 1 and the leading and trailing ones are ignored. With `zsh` and `ksh93` (not `bash`), you can change it to `IFS=$'\n\n'` for newline not to be treated specially, however note that all *trailing* newline characters (so that includes trailing empty lines) will always be removed by the command substitution.

Or [with `read`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read) (no more `cat`):

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "tester: $line"
done < "$1"
```

There, empty lines are preserved, but note that it would skip the last line if it was not properly delimited by a newline character.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know one could `<` into a whole loop. Although it makes perfectly sense now I saw it

Comment: I see `IFS \ read -r line' in second example. Is really `IFS=` needed ? IMHO it enough to say : `while read -r line; do   echo "tester: $line"; done < "$1"`

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki `IFS=` turns off the stripping of leading and trailing whitespace. See [In `while IFS= read..`, why does IFS have no effect?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18922/in-while-ifs-read-why-does-ifs-have-no-effect)

Comment: Why is it important to disable globbing here?

Comment: @BenMares To prevent globbing expressions possibly appearing in the text we are reading from being expanded to matching file names. Try, for instance, `printf '%s\n' '*o' 'bar' >afile; touch foo; IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(cat afile); do echo "$i"; done`.

Comment: A `while IFS= read -r line || [ "$line" ]; do` will process a trailing line not properly delimited by a newline character (but it will be added back).

Answer (score 5):

If you can avoid it, don't especially if it's to process text.

Most text utilities are already designed to process text one line at a time, and, at least for the GNU implementations, do it efficiently, correctly and handle error conditions nicely. Piping one to another which runs them in parallel also means you can leverage more than one processor to do the job.

Here:

```
<input.txt sed 's/^/tester /' > output.txt
```

Or:

```
<input.txt awk '{print "tester", $0}' > output.txt
```

More on that at: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

If it's not about text processing and you do need to run some command per line of a file, also note GNU `xargs` where you can do:

```
xargs -rd'\n' -I@ -a input.txt cp -- @ @.back
```

for instance.

With the bash shell, you can get each line of a file into an array with the `readarray` builtin:

```
readarray -t lines < input.txt &&
  for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    do-some-non-text-processing-you-cannot-easily-do-with-xargs "$line" || break
  done
```

POSIXly, you can use `IFS= read -r line` to read one line off some input, but beware that if you redirect the whole `while read` loop with the input file on stdin, then commands inside the loop will also have their stdin redirected to the file, so best is to use a different fd which you close inside the loop:

```
while
  IFS= read -r line <&3 ||
    [ -n "$line" ] # to cover for an unterminated last line.
do
  {
    do-some-non-text-processing-you-cannot-easily-do-with-xargs "$line" ||
      break # abort upon failure if relevant
  } 3<&-
done 3< input.txt > output.txt
```

`read -r line` removes leading and trailing whitespace characters from the line that it reads provided they are in the `$IFS` variable, though only the `yash` shell honours that POSIX requirement. With most shells, that's limited to space and tab. ksh93 and recent versions of `bash` do it for all single-byte characters considered as whitespace in the locale.

So to read a line and also strip leading and trailing blanks, you can do: `IFS=$' \t' read -r line`. With ksh93, yash¹ or recent versions of `bash`. `IFS=$' \t\r'` would also strip the trailing CR character found in text files from the Microsoft world.

---

<sup>¹ though `yash` doesn't support the `$'...'` syntax yet, you'd need `IFS=$(printf ' \t\r')` there.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth, I need to do that quite often, and can never remember the exact way of using `while IFS= read...`, so I defined the following function in my bash profile:

```
# iterate the line of a file and call input function
iterlines() {
    (( $# < 2 )) && { echo "Usage: iterlines <File> <Callback>"; return; }
    local File=$1
    local Func=$2
    n=$(cat "$File" | wc -l)
    for (( i=1; i<=n; i++ )); do
        "$Func" "$(sed "${i}q;d" "$File")"
    done
}
```

This function first determines the number of lines in the file, then uses `sed` to extract line after line, and passes each line as a single string argument to any given function. I suppose this might get really inefficient with large files, but that hasn't been a problem for me so far (suggestions on how to improve this welcome of course).

The usage is pretty sweet IMO:

```
>> cat example.txt # note the use of spaces, whitespace, etc.
a/path

This is a sentence.
"wi\th quotes"
$End
>> iterlines example.txt echo # preserves quotes, $ and whitespace
a/path

This is a sentence.
"wi\th quotes"
$End
>> x() { echo "$#"; }; iterlines example.txt x # line always passed as single input string
1
1 
1
1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

To read all the lines, regardless of whether they are ended with a new line or not:

```
cat "somefile" | { cat ; echo ; } | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

Source : My open source project https://sourceforge.net/projects/command-output-to-html-table/

Comment: [It is not acceptable to post identical answers to multiple questions.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5849/108618)

Comment: Hi Kamil Maciorowski, Answers are identical because Questions are identical too !

Answer (score -1):

There is an answer here that may be useful to people who this doesn't work for

[loop through file by row in tcsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678487/loop-through-file-by-row-in-tcsh/678531#678531)

Comment: Not an answer as these usually contain some sort of explanation and/or a procedure to follow. A comment at best but not even a good one?