# What is the "IFS" variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I was reading this Q&A: [How to loop over the lines of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file)

What is the `IFS` variable? And what is its usage in the context of `for`-loops?

Comment: I notice that the answers mostly focus on the definition if the IFS internal variable, and not how to "see" (i.e. human-readable) what it contains, which is a possible interpretation of this question. Simply trying to echo the variable will mostly get a blank line, as the default contents is non-printable. Use a hex viewer to "see": eg. > echo "$IFS" | hexdump. Then look up the codes in an ASCII or matching character table for your system.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`IFS` stands for <strike>`Input`</strike> `Internal Field Separator` - it's a character that separates fields. In the example you posted, it is set to new line character (`\n`); so after you set it, `for` will process text line by line. In that example, you could change the value of `IFS` (to some letter that you have in your input file) and check how text will be split.

BTW, from the answer you posted the second solution is the recommended one...

As [@jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6761/jasonwryan) noticed, it's not `Input` but `Internal`. Name `Input` came from `awk` in which there is also `OFS` - `Output Field Separator`.

Comment: Note that IFS is also used for combining parameters for output.  From the bash man page: "When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable."

Comment: One should also note that while `S` was for _separator_ in the Bourne shell where it originated from. In the Korn shell and most other Bourne-like shell as that has now been specified by `POSIX`, the `S` is for Delimiter (just stretch your imagination a bit) as `A::B:` for instance is split into "A", "" and "B" (no extra ""). That's different from `awk`'s `FS` or the `s` parameter expansion flag of `zsh`.

Answer (score 35):

`IFS` isn't directly related to looping, it's related to word splitting. `IFS` indirectly determines how the output from the command is broken up into pieces that the loop iterates over.

When you have an unprotected variable substitution `$foo` or command substitution `$(foo)`, there are two cases:

- If the context expects a single word, e.g. when the substitution is between double quotes `"$foo"`, or in a variable assignment `x=$foo`, then the string resulting from the substitution is used as-is.
- If the context expects multiple words, which is the case most of the times, then two further expansions are performed on the resulting string:

  - The string is [split into words](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05). Any character that appears in `$IFS` is considered a word separator. For example `IFS=":"; foo="12:34::78"; echo $foo` prints `12 34 ​ 78` (with two spaces between `34` and `78`, since there's an empty word).
  - Each word is treated as a glob pattern and [expanded into a list of file names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_06). For example, `foo="*"; echo $foo` prints the list of files in the current directory.

For loops, like many other contexts, expect a list of words. So

```
for x in $(foo); do …
```

breaks `$(foo)` into words, and treats each word as a glob pattern. The default value of `IFS` is [space, tab and newline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_05_03), so if `foo` prints out two lines `hello world` and `howdy` then the loop body is executed with `x=hello`, then `x=world` and `x=howdy`. If `IFS` is explicitly changed to contain a newline only, then the loop is executed for `hello world` and `howdy`. If `IFS` is changed to be `o`, then the loop is executed for `hell`, `​ w`, `rld​␤h` (where `​␤` is a newline character) and `wdy`.

Comment: Why you mentioned "Indirectly" in _`"IFS indirectly determines how ..."`_?

Comment: @αғsнιη `IFS` (directly) determines how the output of the command substitution is broken up, which then (indirectly) determines what the loop loops over.

Comment: For a very long time I was thinking that I was understanding that but I was wrong. The first paragraph could be  misleading, IMO it should mention explicitly that literal strings are not splitted.

Answer (score 7):

From `man bash`

> IFS The Internal Field Separator that is used for word splitting after expansion and to split lines into words with the  read  builtin command.    The   default   value   is "<space><tab><newline>".

This is one of Bash's internal variables. It determines how Bash recognizes fields, or word boundaries, when it interprets character strings.

While it defaults to whitespace (space, tab, and newline), it may be changed, for example, to parse a comma-separated data file.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous great answers, let me just add that **IFS** is very useful for efficient and portable parsing in simple cases in combination with **set**. Efficient, because avoids using of subshells and spawning tools like grep or sed:

```
resolutions="640x480,320x240"
xIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
for res in $resolutions; do
    xxIFS=$IFS
    IFS='x'
    set -- $res
    width=$1
    height=$2
    # handle width and height
    IFS=$xxIFS
done;
IFS=$xIFS
```

Just note that we need to store and recover previous value of **IFS** to avoid undesired breakages in other parts of script.