# Shell script output incorrectly splitting while being passed as an argument to script

Tags: shell, shell-script, quoting

Let's say I have the following two shell scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
#This script is named: args.sh

echo 1 "\"Two words\"" 3
```

, and:

```
#!/bin/sh
#This script is named: test.sh

echo "Argument 1: "$1
echo "Argument 2: "$2
echo "Argument 3: "$3
```

When I call the scripts as:

```
sh test.sh $(sh args.sh)
```

, I recieve:

```
Argument 1: 1
Argument 2: "Two
Argument 3: words"
```

When I expected instead to get:

```
Argument 1: 1
Argument 2: Two words
Argument 3: 3
```

Copying the output of `sh args.sh` and pasting it as the input of `sh test.sh` works just fine; so I assume this isn't actually what the shell is doing.  I can achieve the desired/expected output by calling `sh args.sh | xargs sh test.sh` instead.

However, I'm wondering if there's an equivalent way of doing this without piping the output of the first script (args.sh) to xargs?  I want the scripts to be called in the original order; the argument script to output the parameters to the second.  I'm also looking for an explanation as to why this call doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 4):

Part of the problem is that the string returned by args.sh is not parsed the same as a direct command, but only by the value of $IFS (`$' \t\n'`).  Try turning on command tracing with `set -x`:

```
$ sh /tmp/test.sh $(sh /tmp/args.sh)
++ sh /tmp/args.sh
+ sh /tmp/test.sh 1 '"Two' 'words"' 3
Argument 1: 1
Argument 2: "Two
Argument 3: words"
$
```

Notice the line starting with a single `+`: there are four arguments, the `'"Two'` and `'words"'` are two parsed as separate arguments.  What you would want to do is change $IFS.

```
$ set -x
$ IFS='"'
+ IFS='"'
$ sh /tmp/test.sh $(sh /tmp/args.sh)
++ sh /tmp/args.sh
+ sh /tmp/test.sh '1 ' 'Two words' ' 3'
Argument 1: 1
Argument 2: Two words
Argument 3:  3
$
```

This won't work for every output.  The best thing to do is to change the output of args.sh to separate the output by something different from a space, for example a comma or colon:

```
$ cat /tmp/args.sh
#!/bin/sh
#This script is named: args.sh

echo "1,Two words,3"
$ IFS=,
$ sh /tmp/test.sh $(sh /tmp/args.sh)
+ sh /tmp/args.sh
+ sh /tmp/test.sh 1 Two words 3
Argument 1: 1
Argument 2: Two words
Argument 3: 3
$
```

Answer (score 0):

When you leave a variable substitution `$var` or a command substitution `$(cmd)` unquoted, the result undergoes the following transformations:

1. Split the resulting string into words. The split happens at whitespace (sequences of space, tabs and newlines); this can be configured by setting `IFS` (see [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16192/what-is-ifs-in-context-of-for-looping/16195#16195), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26784/understanding-ifs/26830#26830)).
2. Each of the resulting word is treated as a glob pattern, and if it matches some files, the word is replaced by the list of file names.

Note that the result is not a string but a list of strings. Furthermore, note that quote characters like `"` are not involved here; they are part of the shell source syntax, not of string expansion.

A general rule of shell programming is to always put double quotes around variable and command substitutions, unless you know why you have to leave them off. So in `test.sh`, write `echo "Argument 1: $1"`. To pass arguments to `test.sh`, you're in trouble: you need to pass a list of words from `args.sh` to `test.sh`, but your chosen method involves a command substitution and that only provides the way for a simple string.

If you can guarantee that the arguments to be passed do not contain any newlines, and it is acceptable to change the invocation process slightly, you can set `IFS` to contain only a newline. Make sure that `args.sh` outputs exactly one file name per line with no stray quotes.

```
IFS='
'
test.sh $(args.sh)
unset IFS
```

If the arguments may contain arbitrary characters (presumably except null bytes, which you cannot pass as arguments), you'll need to perform some encoding. Any encoding will do; of course, it won't be the same as passing the arguments directly: that's not possible. For example, in `args.sh` (replace `\t` by an actual tab character if your shell doesn't support it):

```
for x; do
  printf '%s_\n' "$x" |
  sed -e 's/q/qq/g' -e 's/ /qs/g' -e 's/\t/qt/g' -e 's/$/qn/'
done
```

and in `test.sh`:

```
for arg; do
  decoded=$(printf '%s\n' "$arg" |
            sed -e 's/qs/ /g' -e 's/qt/\t/g' -e 's/qn/\n/g' -e 's/qq/q/g')
  decoded=${decoded%_qn}
  # process "$decoded"
done
```

You may prefer to change `test.sh` to accept a list of strings as input. If the strings don't contain newlines, invoke `args.sh | test.sh` and use this in `args.sh` ([explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read)):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  # process "$line"
done
```

Another method that prevents the need for quoting altogether is to invoke the second script from the first.

```
…
args.sh "$@"
```