# Why does using array and for loop breaks line into 2?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Why does the following gives the line I am searching:

```
grep '<appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>' test.xml  
OUTPUT is <appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>
```

While the following breaks it into 2 lines?

```
a=($(grep '<appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>' test.xml))  
for i in "${a[@]}"; do  
    echo "checking $i"   
    grep  -n "$i" delete.xml
done
```

The output is:

```
checking <appointment-id
checking internal:ref=1.2.3/>
```

The file is:

```
<note>  
    <to>Jim</to>  
    <from>John</from>  
    <heading>Reminder</heading>  
    <body>Some text</body>  
    <appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/> 
</note>
```

Comment: because word splitting happening per default `IFS=$' \t\n'`. see [What is the 'IFS'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16192/72456)

Comment: The first solution in [How to loop over the lines of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7012/170373) should work in this case too, to fill the array. The second could be used directly, without an array at all, or to build the array with array extension (`a+=("$line")`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of the `grep` is a string containing two whitespace-separated words.

The shell will split that into two words since it's unquoted, and the array will therefore have two entries.

This will do what you want:

```
a=( "$( grep -F '<appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>' test.xml )" )
```

However, [parsing XML with `grep` is a horrible idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577060/why-is-it-such-a-bad-idea-to-parse-xml-with-regex). Use a proper XML parser instead.

Also, the loop, if all it does is outputting a string, may be replaced by

```
printf 'checking %s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

---

To see who made a change to a line matching a pattern in a particular revision of a `git`-controlled file (see comments below), use `git blame -L` with the pattern and revision in question.  See `git blame --help` for further info.

---

Also note that to get the line number of a line matching a pattern:

```
sed -n '/pattern/=' file
```

Don't ever feed the result of `grep` into `grep` again just to get the line number.  If doing so, be sure to use `grep -F`, or it will fail if the line contains regular expression patterns.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78701/discussion-on-answer-by-kusalananda-why-does-using-array-and-for-loop-breaks-lin).