# name a variable using the file name

Tags: linux, bash, centos, scripting

I have a file with this format name `Pocket_???_????_?.pdb_OUTPUT.txt` and some directory with this format ????_?. I need to copy some of this file. For example, I have a list of file and I want to copy only this file in my final directory.

For example:

```
file.txt:

Pocket_001_1b47_A.pdb_OUTPUT.txt
Pocket_002_1b47_A.pdb_OUTPUT.txt
Pocket_001_2cl5_B.pdb_OUTPUT.txt
Pocket_001_4rtl_A.pdb_OUTPUT.txt
```

Each of these files is within its own directory (`1b47_A`, `2cl5_B` and `4rt1_A`) and I would like to enter in each directory and copy them to another destination. The problem is that I do not know how to indicate the directory on the basis of the file name.

I try to use this scripting and this well works but it process all the directory ????_? and since they are many it takes a long time.

```
for dir in ????_?; 
    do cd $dir/; 
       while read file; 
       do cp $file /home/tommaso/cp_file/; done < /home/tommaso/file.txt ; 
    cd .. ; cd .. ; done
```

I would like to tell the script to search for files only in direcotry contained in the file name. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be an option:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r file; do 
  dir="${file%%.*}"
  cp "${dir#*_*_}/$file" /home/tommaso/cp_file/
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Could you explain the regular expressions that you used? And what does IFS mean?

Comment: @TommasoPalomba It's not a regex, is called [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: @TommasoPalomba  [About IFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16192/what-is-the-ifs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to print `directory/filename` together with `xargs` and `cp -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...`:

```bsh
awk -F"[_.]"  '{printf "%s_%s/%s\n",$3,$4,$0}' file.txt \
| xargs -d '\n' cp -t /home/tommaso/cp_file/
```