# How can I extract all the bin directories from PATH in one-liner?

Tags: path

I'd like to extract all `bin` directories from `PATH` and set it to a variable. I get confused because all the directories appear in a row separated by `:` but I just want the `bin` ones.

```
/home/jo52900/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/opt/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin:/local/bin:/opt/universal/ucmdmgr/bin
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to treat the `bin` directories specially, I am guessing that you just want to see each directory on its own line. If so, you can just do:

```
printf '%s\n' "$PATH" | tr : '\n'
```

On my system, for example, where I have many directories in my `$PATH` whose name doesn't contain `bin`, that gives:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$PATH" | tr : '\n' 
/home/terdon/perl5/bin
/home/terdon/Setups/cd-hit-v4.5.4-2011-03-07
/sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/usr/sbin
/home/terdon/Setups/PfamScan
/home/terdon/research/data/python
/home/terdon/scripts
/home/terdon/bin
```

If you really only want to see the `bin` directories, you can extract them:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$PATH" | tr : '\n' | grep '/bin$'
/home/terdon/saphetor/bin
/home/terdon/perl5/bin
/usr/bin
/home/terdon/bin
```

Or, if you want to do what you show in your answer and also include any directory that hjas the string `bin` anywhere in its name, and not only those that are actually *named* `bin`, you can do:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$PATH" | tr : '\n' | grep 'bin'
/home/terdon/saphetor/bin
/home/terdon/perl5/bin
/sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/usr/sbin
/home/terdon/bin
```

Comment: just a curiosity, why do you use `printf` instead of `echo $PATH | tr : "\n"`?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira see [why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222). Especially when printing a variable that can contain just about anything, printf will be more robust.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to ask the shell to split `$PATH`:

```
( IFS=: ; printf "%s\n" $PATH )
```

You can post-process this with `grep` as necessary.

Comment: what is `IFS=:`?

Comment: found it :) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16192/what-is-the-ifs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using zsh:

```
print -lr $path
```

The [`path` variable](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-path) is an array which is automatically synchronized with the colon-separated string in `PATH`. [`print -lr`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print) prints one element per line without doing backslash interpretation¹.

In case you need this for some other colon-separated list that doesn't have a tied array, you can do the splitting explicitly through a [parameter expansion flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

```
print -lr ${(s[:])LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

I don't know what you mean by “bin directories”. You can filter using grep, e.g.

```
print -lr $path | grep bin
```

Or using [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) features, e.g.

```
print -lr ${(M)path:#*bin*}
```

¹  <sub>For the nitpickers: this assumes that the list is not empty and the first element does not start with `-`. Which is a safe bet for `$path`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```bsh
echo "$PATH" | grep -o "[^:]*bin[^:]*"
```

Comment: Note that this will only work on systems where `grep` has an `-o` option. GNU and BSD `grep` have this, so it will work on Linux and Mac, but I don't know about other Unices.