# In `while IFS= read..`, why does IFS have no effect?

Tags: shell, text-processing, environment-variables

I might have something absolutely wrong, but it looks convincing to me, that setting IFS as one of the **commands** in the pre-do/done list has absolutely no effect.
The outer IFS (outside the `while` construct) prevails in all examples shown in the script below..

What's going on here?  Have I got the wrong idea of what IFS does in this situation? I expected the array-split results to be as shown in the "expected" column.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
xifs() { echo -n "$(echo -n "$IFS" | xxd -p)"; } # allow for null $IFS 
show() { x=($1) 
         echo -ne "  (${#x[@]})\t |"
         for ((j=0;j<${#x[@]};j++)); do 
           echo -n "${x[j]}|"
         done
         echo -ne "\t"
         xifs "$IFS"; echo
}
data="a  b   c"
echo -e "-----   --  -- \t --------\tactual"
echo -e "outside        \t  IFS    \tinside" 
echo -e "loop           \t Field   \tloop" 
echo -e "IFS     NR  NF \t Split   \tIFS (actual)" 
echo -e "-----   --  -- \t --------\t-----"
IFS=$' \t\n'; xifs "$IFS"; echo "$data" | while         read; do echo -ne '\t 1'; show "$REPLY"; done 
IFS=$' \t\n'; xifs "$IFS"; echo "$data" | while IFS=    read; do echo -ne '\t 2'; show "$REPLY"; done 
IFS=$' \t\n'; xifs "$IFS"; echo "$data" | while IFS=b   read; do echo -ne '\t 3'; show "$REPLY"; done
IFS=" ";      xifs "$IFS"; echo "$data" | while         read; do echo -ne '\t 4'; show "$REPLY"; done 
IFS=" ";      xifs "$IFS"; echo "$data" | while IFS=    read; do echo -ne '\t 5'; show "$REPLY"; done 
IFS=" ";      xifs "$IFS"; echo "$data" | while IFS=b   read; do echo -ne '\t 6'; show "$REPLY"; done
IFS=;         xifs "$IFS"; echo "$data" | while         read; do echo -ne '\t 7'; show "$REPLY"; done 
IFS=;         xifs "$IFS"; echo "$data" | while IFS=" " read; do echo -ne '\t 8'; show "$REPLY"; done 
IFS=;         xifs "$IFS"; echo "$data" | while IFS=b   read; do echo -ne '\t 9'; show "$REPLY"; done
IFS=b;        xifs "$IFS"; echo "$data" | while IFS=    read; do echo -ne '\t10'; show "$REPLY"; done
IFS=b;        xifs "$IFS"; echo "$data" | while IFS=" " read; do echo -ne '\t11'; show "$REPLY"; done
echo -e "-----   --  -- \t --------\t-----"
```

---

Output:

```
-----   --  --   --------       actual   
outside           IFS           inside                assigned   
loop             Field          loop    #              inner
IFS     NR  NF   Split          IFS     #  expected    IFS
-----   --  --   --------       -----   #  ---------  --------
20090a   1  (3)  |a|b|c|        20090a  #                              
20090a   2  (3)  |a|b|c|        20090a  #  |a  b   c|  IFS=
20090a   3  (3)  |a|b|c|        20090a  #  |a  |   c|  IFS=b
20       4  (3)  |a|b|c|        20      #                          
20       5  (3)  |a|b|c|        20      #  |a  b   c   IFS=
20       6  (3)  |a|b|c|        20      #  |a  |   c|  IFS=b
         7  (1)  |a  b   c|             #                          
         8  (1)  |a  b   c|             #  |a|b|c|     IFS=" "
         9  (1)  |a  b   c|             #  |a  |   c|  IFS=b
62      10  (2)  |a  |   c|     62      #  |a  b   c|  IFS=
62      11  (2)  |a  |   c|     62      #  |a|b|c|     IFS=" "
-----   --  --   --------       -----      ---------   -------
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(Sorry, long explanation)

Yes, the `IFS` variable in `while IFS=" " read; do …` has no effect on the rest of the code.

Let's first specify that the shell command line features two different kinds of variables:

- shell variables (which only exist within a shell, and are local to the shell)
- environment variables, which exist for every process. Those are usually preserved upon `fork()` and `exec()`, so child processes inherit them.

When you call a command with:

```
  A=foo B=bar command
```

the command is executed within an environment where (environment) variable `A` is set to `foo` and `B` is set to `bar`.  But with this command line, the current shell variables `A` and `B` are are left *unchanged*.

This is different from:

```
A=foo; B=bar; command
```

Here, shell variables `A` and `B` are defined and the command is run without environment variables `A` and `B` defined. Values of `A` and `B` are unaccessible from `command`.

However, if some shell variables are `export`-ed, the corresponding environment variables are synchronized with their respective shell variables. Example:

```
export A
export B
A=foo; B=bar; command
```

With this code, both *shell* variables and the shell *environment* variables are set to `foo` and `bar`. Since environment variables are inherited by sub-processes, `command` will be able to access their values.

To jump back to your original question, in:

```
IFS='a' read
```

only `read` is affected. And in fact, in this case, `read` doesn't care about the value of the `IFS` variable. It uses `IFS` only when you ask the line to be split (and stored in several variables), like in:

```
echo "a :  b :    c" | IFS=":" read i j k; \
    printf "i is '%s', j is '%s', k is '%s'" "$i" "$j" "$k"
```

`IFS` is not used by `read` unless it is called with arguments. (**Edit:** This is not exactly true: whitespace characters, i.e. space and tab, present in `IFS` are always ignored at the beginning/end of the input line. )

Comment: What a great explanation! It is so simple! I've been bemused by that *'no semi-colon'* syntax for months; and it is simply a case of it meaning a local variable!..   *rozcietrzewiacz* opened the pathway for me (big-time) in the [other question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read) ... and you have just put the icing on the cake... I've been up all night on this one, and it has certainly been worth it for such good and clear answers! .. Thank you..

Comment: Uhm. I had to read that edit comment several times before I got it – you mean to say that whitespace characters which are present in `$IFS` are removed at the beginning/end of the input line, I presume? (Which is how it works.)

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382963/read-r-vs-read-r-line-and-ifs

Comment: The value of IFS *is* important even when reading a single variable, because the shell still does word splitting on the input.  So for example, typing the characters `a<tab>b` into `read var` will result in var having the value `a<space>b`, but if instead you have `IFS='<newline>' read var` then the value of var will be `a<tab>b`.

Answer (score 9):

Put it simple, **you must read to more than one variable at a time** for the `IFS=<something> read ...` construct to have a visible effect in your examples<sup>1</sup>.

You miss the scope of `read` in the examples. There is **no** modification of IFS inside the loop in your test cases. Allow me to point exactly, where does the second IFS have its effect in each of your lines:

```
 IFS=$' \t\n'; xifs "$IFS"; echo "$data" | while IFS=b   read; do echo ...
                                                      ^      ^
                                                      |      |
                                          from here --'       `- to here :)
```

It is just as with any program executed in the shell. The variable you (re)define at the command-line affects the program execution. And *only* that (since you do not export). Therefore, to make a use of redefined `IFS` in such line, you'd have to ask `read` to assign values to *more than one variable*. Have a look a these examples:

```
 $ data="a  b   c"
 $ echo "$data" | while           read A B C; do echo \|$A\|$B\|\|$C\|; done
 |a|b||c|
 $ echo "$data" | while IFS=      read A B C; do echo \|$A\|$B\|\|$C\|; done
 |a b c||||
 $ echo "$data" | while IFS='a'   read A B C; do echo \|$A\|$B\|\|$C\|; done
 || b c|||
 $ echo "$data" | while IFS='ab'  read A B C; do echo \|$A\|$B\|\|$C\|; done
 || || c|
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> As I've just learned [from Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read/18936#18936), there might actually be a benefit of setting `IFS=''` (blank) when reading only one field: it avoids truncation of whitespace at the beginning of the line.</sub>

Comment: Good.. Thanks... I got it this time.. and I love your sketch :)

Comment: OK, now I've read your comment that see you haven't noticed my answer to that issue in the other question. Maybe you could just revert the other one and delete this, since it really is one general issue?

Comment: Yes, the two questions do have a related theme, but the title of the other one is "Why is `IFS= read` used in preference to just re-setting the IFS environment variable".  I didn't have awareness, then, that local variables could be set by the caller of a command. That was the answer to that question. It did evolve further to addressing this question's main point, but by the time I realized that, I had already asked this question... Perhaps the two questions are as similar as two `sed` questions, so my feeling it to keep it asis... More *titles* for googlers to google.