# Bash iterate over a list of strings

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, busybox

I have this bash script:

```
for opt in string1 string2 string3 ... string99
do somestuff
```

It works, but I would like to replace the explicit listing of my strings with a file which actually contains all the strings; something like this:

```
strings=loadFromFile
for opt in $strings
do somestuff
```

How should I do this?

Comment: See [Why is `while IFS= read` used so often, instead of `IFS=; while read..`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18886) and [In `while IFS= read..`, why does IFS have no effect?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18922)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`while read VAR` is probably best here, as it handles per-line input. You can redirect it from a file, e.g.:

```
while IFS= read -r THELINE; do
  echo "..$THELINE"
done </path/to/file
```

That'll give you each line prepended with ".."

For your example case:

```
while IFS= read -r opt; do
  #somestuff $opt
done </path/to/file
```

See [Why is `while IFS= read` used so often, instead of `IFS=; while read..`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read/18936#18936) for explanations.

Comment: Putting cats into pipes is bad behavior from a memory management point of view. especially when using "filter" built-in commands.
@rush's answer is better, and what I use on a daily basis.

Comment: It also puts the `while` loop into a subshell, which can cause confusing behaviour if update variable values in the loop (the values will disappear when the subshell exits)

Comment: If `somestuff` includes another `read`, this seems not to work properly.

Comment: @raphael - in what way does it not "work properly"? I just tried nested reads and it works fine.

Comment: @IBBoard See [this new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65955/nested-read-fails).

Answer (score 8):

```
while IFS= read -r opt
do 
    some_stuff
done < file_with_string
```

See [Why is `while IFS= read` used so often, instead of `IFS=; while read..`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18886/why-is-while-ifs-read-used-so-often-instead-of-ifs-while-read/18936#18936) for explanations.

Answer (score 4):

The `while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done < aFile` is the best answer

If your strings do **not** contain whitespace or `\[*?`, you could do

```
for word in $(< aFile); do something; done
```

`$(< file)` is a bash feature that reads the file (like `cat` except without having to spawn a new process).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the `readarray` builtin (requires `bash >= 4.0`)?

```
readarray < FileNameFromWhereToLoad    # push every line of 
                                       # 'FileNameFromWhereToLoad' onto 
                                       # $MAPFILE by default

for i in $MAPFILE ; do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: This also requires newer version of bash.

Comment: i wouldn't call `bash >= 4` new (release date was February 2009)!

Comment: Since he's using 2.05a, it is newer than what the asker has. In addition, some companies have avoided GPLv3 versions of bash, so do not have it in their system.

Comment: Do you have a crystal ball around? But yes, i agree with you about your last statement, i will add the version requirement of `readarray` to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I have a crystal ball which reflects the comment the poster wrote an hour ago on @h-dirk-schmitt answer.

Comment: I didn't read that. Thanks for the hint ;) Maybe my answer is of value for somebody who will search for an answer for a similar question!?

Answer (score 1):

My advice:

```
cat INPUTFILE| {
  declare -a LINES
  mapfile -t LINES
  for line in "${LINES[@]}"
  do
    somestuff
  done
}
```

Comment: Syntax error: bad substitution

Comment: Works for me. @michelemarcon, is your `bash` 4.00 or never?

Comment: GNU bash, version 2.05a.0(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnu)

Comment: That is ancient. Please specify this requirement in the question.

Comment: osx 10.12.2 has ancient bash ; $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.