# Nested read fails

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, test, read

I have a list of filenames in a file and want to do let the user decide what to do with each. In bash, iterating over filenames is not trivial in itself, so I followed [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48607/17409):

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r THELINE; 
do
  read -n 1 -p "Print line? [y/n] " answer;
  if [ ${answer} = "y" ];
  then
    echo "${THELINE}";
  fi;
done < tester;
```

When I try to execute this (on a non-empty file), I get an error at the `if`:

```
line 5: [: =: unary operator expected
```

My best guess is that `answer` is not set properly, which would be caused by using two calls of `read` in a "nested" fashion since the following works as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash

for THELINE in $(cat "tester");
do
  read -n 1 -p "Print line? [y/n] " answer;
  if [ ${answer} = "y" ];
  then
    echo "${THELINE}";
  fi;
done;
```

What is going on here?

I run `bash 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` on `3.2.0-37-generic #58-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: try replacing the `${answer} = "y"` with `"${answer}" == "y"`

Comment: @mauro.stettler: That gets rid of the error. Now the script does iterate, but never prompts.

Comment: I'm not sure what the scope of the IFS= in your first `while` is, that might mess up things.

Comment: @vonbrand [The scope is the `read` command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18922/in-while-ifs-read-why-does-ifs-have-no-effect).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the error from `[` is because `answer` is empty, so `[` sees three arguments: `=`, `y` and `]`. Always put double quotes around variable substitutions: `if [ "$answer" = "y" ]`.

The reason `$answer` is empty fd 0 is busy with the file input due to the redirection `<tester` over the while loop.

```
while IFS= read -r line <&3
do
    read -n 1 -p "Print line? [y/n] " answer
    if test "$answer" = "y"
    then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done 3< tester
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `if [ x${answer} = "xy" ];`. `test` does need something before `=`