# Command line tool to "cat" pairwise expansion of all rows in a file

Tags: shell, shell-script, text-processing, awk

Suppose I have a file (call it sample.txt) that looks like this:

```
Row1,10
Row2,20
Row3,30
Row4,40
```

I want to be able to work on a stream from this file that is essentially the pairwise combination of all four rows (so we should end up with 16 in total). For instance, I'm looking for a streaming (ie efficient) command where the output is:

```
Row1,10 Row1,10
Row1,10 Row2,20
Row1,10 Row3,30
Row1,10 Row4,40
Row2,20 Row1,10
Row1,20 Row2,20
...
Row4,40 Row4,40
```

My use case is that I want to stream this output into another command (like awk) to compute some metric about this pairwise combination.

I have a way to do this in awk but my concern is that my use of the END{} block means that I'm basically storing the entire file in memory before I output. Example code:

```
awk '{arr[$1]=$1} END{for (a in arr){ for (a2 in arr) { print arr[a] " " arr[a2]}}}' samples/rows.txt 
Row3,30 Row3,30
Row3,30 Row4,40
Row3,30 Row1,10
Row3,30 Row2,20
Row4,40 Row3,30
Row4,40 Row4,40
Row4,40 Row1,10
Row4,40 Row2,20
Row1,10 Row3,30
Row1,10 Row4,40
Row1,10 Row1,10
Row1,10 Row2,20
Row2,20 Row3,30
Row2,20 Row4,40
Row2,20 Row1,10
Row2,20 Row2,20
```

Is there an efficient streaming way to do this without having to essentially store the file in memory and then output in the END block?

Comment: You'll always need to read one file to the end before being able to start producing output for the second line of the other file.  The other file you can stream.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's how to do it in awk so that it doesn't have to store the whole file in an array. This is basically the same algorithm as terdon's.

If you like, you can even give it multiple filenames on the command line and it will process each file independently, concatenating the results together.

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

#Cartesian product of records

{
    file = FILENAME
    while ((getline line <file) > 0)
        print $0, line
    close(file)
}
```

On my system, this runs in about 2/3 the time of terdon's perl solution.

Comment: Thanks! All the solutions to this problem were fantastic but I ended up going with this one due to 1) simplicity and 2) staying in awk. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you like it, Tom. I tend to program mostly in Python these days, but I still like awk for line by line text processing because of its built-in loops over lines and files. And it's often faster than Python.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure this is better than doing it in memory, but with a `sed` that `r`eads out its infile for every line in its infile and another on the other side of a pipe alternating `H`old space with input lines...

```
cat <<\IN >/tmp/tmp
Row1,10
Row2,20
Row3,30
Row4,40
IN

</tmp/tmp sed -e 'i\
' -e 'r /tmp/tmp' | 
sed -n '/./!n;h;N;/\n$/D;G;s/\n/ /;P;D'
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Row1,10 Row1,10
Row1,10 Row2,20
Row1,10 Row3,30
Row1,10 Row4,40
Row2,20 Row1,10
Row2,20 Row2,20
Row2,20 Row3,30
Row2,20 Row4,40
Row3,30 Row1,10
Row3,30 Row2,20
Row3,30 Row3,30
Row3,30 Row4,40
Row4,40 Row1,10
Row4,40 Row2,20
Row4,40 Row3,30
Row4,40 Row4,40
```

I did this another way. It does store *some* in memory - it stores a string like:

```
"$1" -
```

... for each line in the file.

```
pairs(){ [ -e "$1" ] || return
    set -- "$1" "$(IFS=0 n=
        case "${0%sh*}" in (ya|*s) n=-1;; (mk|po) n=+1;;esac
        printf '"$1" - %s' $(printf "%.$(($(wc -l <"$1")$n))d" 0))"
    eval "cat -- $2 </dev/null | paste -d ' \n' -- $2"
}
```

It is very fast. It `cat`'s the file as many times as there are lines in the file to a `|pipe`. On the other side of the pipe that input is merged with the file itself as many times as there are lines in the file.

The `case` stuff is just for portability - `yash` and `zsh` both add one element to the split, while `mksh` and `posh` both lose one. `ksh`, `dash`, `busybox`, and `bash` all split out to exactly as many fields as there are zeroes as printed by `printf`. As written the above renders the same results for every one of the above mentioned shells on my machine.

If the file is *very* long, there may be `$ARGMAX` issues with too many arguments in which case you would need to introduce `xargs` or similar as well.

Given the same input I used before the output is identical. But, if I were to go bigger...

```
seq 10 10 10000 | nl -s, >/tmp/tmp
```

That generates a file almost identical to what I used before *(sans 'Row')* - but at 1000 lines. You can see for yourself how fast it is:

```
time pairs /tmp/tmp |wc -l

1000000
pairs /tmp/tmp  0.20s user 0.07s system 110% cpu 0.239 total
wc -l  0.05s user 0.03s system 32% cpu 0.238 total
```

At 1000 lines there is some slight variation in performance between shells - `bash` is invariably the slowest - but because the only work they do anyway is generate the arg string *(1000 copies of `filename -`)* the effect is minimal. The difference in performance between `zsh` - as above - and `bash` is 100th of a second here.

Here's another version that should work for a file of any length:

```
pairs2()( [ -e "$1" ] || exit
    rpt() until [ "$((n+=1))" -gt "$1" ]
          do printf %s\\n "$2"
          done
    [ -n "${1##*/*}" ] || cd -P -- "${1%/*}" || exit
    : & set -- "$1" "/tmp/pairs$!.ln" "$(wc -l <"$1")"
    ln -s "$PWD/${1##*/}" "$2" || exit
    n=0 rpt "$3" "$2" | xargs cat | { exec 3<&0
    n=0 rpt "$3" p | sed -nf - "$2" | paste - /dev/fd/3
    }; rm "$2"
)
```

It creates a soft-link to its first arg in `/tmp` with a semi-random name so that it won't get hung-up on weird filenames. That's important because `cat`'s args are fed to it over a pipe via `xargs`. `cat`'s output is saved to `<&3` while `sed` `p`rints every line in the first arg as many times as there are lines in that file - and its script is also fed to it via a pipe. Again `paste` merges its input, but this time it takes only two arguments `-` again for its standard input and the link name `/dev/fd/3`.

That last - the `/dev/fd/[num]` link - should work on any linux system and many more besides, but if it doesn't creating a named pipe with `mkfifo` and using that instead should work as well.

The last thing it does is `rm` the soft-link it creates before exiting.

This version is actually *faster still* on my system. I guess it is because that though it execs more applications, it starts handing them their arguments immediately - whereas before it stacked them all first.

```
time pairs2 /tmp/tmp | wc -l

1000000
pairs2 /tmp/tmp  0.30s user 0.09s system 178% cpu 0.218 total
wc -l  0.03s user 0.02s system 26% cpu 0.218 total
```

Comment: Is the pairs function suppose to be in a file, if not how would you declare it ?

Comment: @Jidder - how would I declare what? You can just copy+paste it into a terminal, no?

Comment: Declare the function. So you can!I thought you would have escape newlines, i am wary of just pasting code in, thanks though :) Also that is extremely fast, nice answer !

Comment: @Jidder - I usually write these in a live shell just using `ctrl+v; ctrl+j` to get newlines as I do.

Comment: @Jidder - thank you very much. And it is wise to be wary - good for you. They will work as well in a file - you can copy it in and `. ./file; fn_name` in that case.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could always do it in your shell:

```
while read i; do 
    while read k; do echo "$i $k"; done < sample.txt 
done < sample.txt
```

It is a good deal slower than your `awk` solution (on my machine, it took ~11 seconds for 1000 lines, versus ~0.3 seconds in `awk`) but at least it never holds more than a couple of lines in memory.

The loop above works for the very simple data you have in your example. It will choke on backslashes and it will eat trailing and leading spaces. A more robust version of the same thing is:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do 
    while IFS= read -r k; do printf "%s %s\n" "$i" "$k"; done < sample.txt 
done < sample.txt
```

---

Another choice is to use `perl` instead:

```
perl -lne '$line1=$_; open(A,"sample.txt"); 
           while($line2=<A>){printf "$line1 $line2"} close(A)' sample.txt
```

The script above will read each line of the input file (`-ln`), save it as `$l`, open `sample.txt` again, and print each line along with `$l`. The result is all pairwise combinations while only 2 lines are ever stored in memory. On my system, that took only about `0.6` seconds on 1000 lines.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I wonder why the perl solution is so much faster than the bash while statement

Comment: @TomHayden basically because perl, like awk, is _much_ faster than bash.

Comment: Had to downvote for your while loop. 4 different bad practices in there. You know better.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas lol, fair enough. Better now? What was the 4th bad practice, I could only see 3. Lack of quotes, no `IFS=` and no `-r`. Do you really consider `echo` instead of `printf` to be a problem in this context where portability doesn't seem relevant?

Comment: You still have _usage of `echo`_ (fails with backslashes with Unix echos) and _usage of a `while read` loop to process text_. How would _portability not be an issue_ in an answer in a public Q&A site? Why would you still advertise the broken version?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas well, based on your answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222), I couldn't think of any cases where the `echo` might be a problem. What I had written (I added `printf` now) should work with all of them right? As for the `while` loop, why? What's wrong with `while read f; do ..; done < file`? Surely you're not suggesting a `for` loop! What's the other alternative?

Comment: On Unix, `echo` is the tool to expand ANSI C escape sequences. It turns `\n` into a newline character for instance. Using shell loops to process text is _generally_ bad practice, if you raise the question, I'll try and answer it at some point, it deserves a long answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Maybe you have answered a similar question [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87301/busy-box-read-file-line-by-line)

Comment: @cuonglm, that one only hints at one possible reason why one should avoid it. Out of the _conceptual_, _reliability_, _legibility_, _performance_ and _security_ aspects, that only covers _reliability_.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Please look at [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/whats-reasons-using-shell-loops-to-process-text-is-generally-considered-bad-pra) and give us an answer.

Comment: What are the specs for your machine, it takes mine 14 seconds to just cat the million line file ?? Or are you saying a thousand lines as though it produces a thousand ?Or are you just not outputting to screen ?

Comment: @Jidder no, I was redirecting the output. I always do when testing since printing to screen is so slow. I tested on an i7 quad-core laptop with 8G RAM.

Comment: @terdon, just curiosity: could you time my (lasy) solution in the same conditions?

Comment: @terdon, please ignore my last comment ( I have not notice this was discusses 3 year ago)

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
a=(
Row1,10
Row2,20
Row3,30
Row4,40
)
printf '%s\n' $^a' '$^a
```

`$^a` on an array turns on brace-like expansion (like in `{elt1,elt2}`) for the array.

Answer (score 4):

You can compile this [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code  for quite quick results.
It completes in around 0.19 - 0.27 seconds on a 1000 line file.

It currently reads `10000` lines into memory(to speed up printing to screen) which if you had `1000` characters per line would use less than `10mb` memory which i wouldn't think would be a problem.
You can remove that section completely though and just print directly to screen if it does cause an issue though.

You can compile using `g++ -o "NAME" "NAME.cpp"`
Where `NAME` is the name of the File to save it to and `NAME.cpp` is the file this code is saved to

`CTEST.cpp:`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

        if(argc != 2)
        {
                printf("You must provide at least one argument\n"); // Make                                                                                                                      sure only one arg
                exit(0);
   }
std::ifstream file(argv[1]),file2(argv[1]);
std::string line,line2;
std::stringstream ss;
int x=0;

while (file.good()){
    file2.clear();
    file2.seekg (0, file2.beg);
    getline(file, line);
    if(file.good()){
        while ( file2.good() ){
            getline(file2, line2);
            if(file2.good())
            ss << line <<" "<<line2 << "\n";
            x++;
            if(x==10000){
                    std::cout << ss.rdbuf();
                    ss.clear();
                    ss.str(std::string());
            }
    }
    }
}
std::cout << ss.rdbuf();
ss.clear();
ss.str(std::string());
}
```

#### Demonstration

```
$ g++ -o "Stream.exe" "CTEST.cpp"
$ seq 10 10 10000 | nl -s, > testfile
$ time ./Stream.exe testfile | wc -l
1000000

real    0m0.243s
user    0m0.210s
sys     0m0.033s
```

Answer (score 3):

```
join -j 2 file.txt file.txt | cut -c 2-
```

- join by a non existing field and remove the first space

Field 2 is empty and equal for all the element in file.txt so `join` will concatenate each element with all the others: it is in fact calculating the Cartesian product.

Answer (score 2):

One option with Python is to [memory-map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) the file and take advantage of the fact that the Python regular expression library can work directly with memory-mapped files. Although this has the appearance of running nested loops over the file, memory mapping ensures that the OS brings available physical RAM optimally into play

```
import mmap
import re
with open('test.file', 'rt') as f1, open('test.file') as f2:
    with mmap.mmap(f1.fileno(), 0, flags=mmap.MAP_SHARED, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as m1,\
        mmap.mmap(f2.fileno(), 0, flags=mmap.MAP_SHARED, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as m2:
        for line1 in re.finditer(b'.*?\n', m1):
            for line2 in re.finditer(b'.*?\n', m2):
                print('{} {}'.format(line1.group().decode().rstrip(),
                    line2.group().decode().rstrip()))
            m2.seek(0)
```

Alternately a quick solution in Python, although memory efficiency might still be a concern

```
from itertools import product
with open('test.file') as f:
    for a, b  in product(f, repeat=2):
        print('{} {}'.format(a.rstrip(), b.rstrip()))
Row1,10 Row1,10
Row1,10 Row2,20
Row1,10 Row3,30
Row1,10 Row4,40
Row2,20 Row1,10
Row2,20 Row2,20
Row2,20 Row3,30
Row2,20 Row4,40
Row3,30 Row1,10
Row3,30 Row2,20
Row3,30 Row3,30
Row3,30 Row4,40
Row4,40 Row1,10
Row4,40 Row2,20
Row4,40 Row3,30
Row4,40 Row4,40
```

Comment: Won't that, by definition, keep the entire file in memory? I don't know Python but your language certainly suggests that it will.

Comment: @terdon, if you are referring to the memory-mapping solution, the OS will transparently keep only as much of the file in memory as it can afford to based on available physical RAM. The available physical RAM does not have to exceed file size(although having extra physical RAM would obviously be an advantageous situation). In the worst case this could degrade to the speed of looping through file on disk or worse. The key advantage with this approach is the transparent usage of available physical RAM as this is something that could fluctuate over time

Answer (score 2):

GNU parallel can do it this way:

```
parallel echo {1} {2} :::: sample.txt :::: sample.txt
```

(If you add `--link` parallel will pair up the corresponding lines, rather than giving the cartesian product.)

And if you need to exclude matching rows:

```
parallel -q bash -c '[[ "{1}" != "{2}" ]] && echo {1} {2}' :::: tmp.a :::: tmp.a
```

Comment: Wow this is really clever

Comment: See also https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html#example-all-combinations-in-a-list if you regard (a,b) == (b,a) which is often the case in pairwise difference.

Comment: @OleTange, thanks, I added your suggestion and example link as a [solution to a related but more restricted question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/732488/77539) that was looking for exactly the case you brought up.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, ksh should work as well, using only shell built-ins:

```
#!/bin/bash
# we require array support
d=( $(< sample.txt) )
# quote arguments and
# build up brace expansion string
d=$(printf -- '%q,' "${d[@]}")
d=$(printf -- '%s' "{${d%,}}' '{${d%,}}")
eval printf -- '%s\\n' "$d"
```

Note that while this holds the entire file in memory in a shell variable, it only needs a single read access to it.

Comment: I think the whole point for the OP is to not hold the file in memory. Otherwise, their current gawk approach is both simpler and _much_ faster. I'm guessing this needs to work with text files that are several gigabytes in size.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly correct - I have a couple HUGE data files that I need to do this with and don't want to hold in memory

Comment: In case you are that constrainted by memory, I would recommend using one of the solutions from @terdon

Answer (score 0):

`sed` solution.

```
line_num=$(wc -l < input.txt)
sed 'r input.txt' input.txt | sed -re "1~$((line_num + 1)){h;d}" -e 'G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/'
```

**Explanation:**

- `sed 'r file2' file1` - read the all file contents of file2 for every line of file1.
- Construction `1~i` means 1-th line, then 1+i line, 1+2*i, 1+3*i, etc. Therefore, `1~$((line_num + 1)){h;d}` means `h`old pointed line to the buffer, `d`elete pattern space and start new cycle.
- `'G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/'` - for all lines, except picked in the previous step, do next: `G`et line from hold buffer and append it to the current line. Then swap places of lines. Was `current_line\nbuffer_line\n`, became `buffer_line\ncurrent_line\n`

**Output**

```
Row1,10 Row1,10
Row1,10 Row2,20
Row1,10 Row3,30
Row1,10 Row4,40
Row2,20 Row1,10
Row2,20 Row2,20
Row2,20 Row3,30
Row2,20 Row4,40
Row3,30 Row1,10
Row3,30 Row2,20
Row3,30 Row3,30
Row3,30 Row4,40
Row4,40 Row1,10
Row4,40 Row2,20
Row4,40 Row3,30
Row4,40 Row4,40
```