# Cost-efficiently pair each line of a file with all others

Tags: text-processing

I have a very huge file containing numbers only.
file -

```
123212
234234
12324
1243223
5453443
```

And want to pair each line with all others. Output like below

```
123212,234234
123212,12324
123212,1243223
123212,5453443
234234,123212
234234,12324
234234,1243223
234234,5453443
12324,123212
12324,234234
12324,1243223
12324,5453443
1243223,123212
1243223,234234
1243223,12324
1243223,5453443
5453443,123212
5453443,234234
5453443,12324
5453443,1243223
```

since the input file contains more than 50L records. so doing it via a loop will be a costly operation.

Comment: What does the `L` mean in `50L`?

Comment: It probably means miss-clicked `K`.

Comment: Very similar to [Pairwise expansion of all rows in a file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169625)

Comment: [GNU parallel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/732407/77539) might handle this efficiently, but I'm not sure how to test that.

Answer (score 1):

All methods for creating this output will be costly.  This approach, however, will work even if the file is much larger than RAM:

```
$ while read n; do awk -v n="$n" '$1!=n{print n "," $1}' file; done <file
123212,234234
123212,12324
123212,1243223
123212,5453443
234234,123212
234234,12324
234234,1243223
234234,5453443
12324,123212
12324,234234
12324,1243223
12324,5453443
1243223,123212
1243223,234234
1243223,12324
1243223,5453443
5453443,123212
5453443,234234
5453443,12324
5453443,1243223
```

#### Written over multiple lines

```
while read n
do
    awk -v n="$n" '$1!=n{print n "," $1}' file
done <file
```

`read n` reads numbers from `file` one at a time.  For each `n`, the awk script is run to create that part of the output for which `n` is in the first column.  The option `-v n="$n"` creates an awk variable named `n` which has the same value as the shell variable `n`.  The condition `$1!=n` selects those lines in `file` for which the number on that line of the file differs from `n`.  For those lines, we print the number `n`, followed by a comma, followed by the number on the line.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with John, this is going to be expensive no matter what.

```
join -o 1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3 -j 1 <(awk '{printf "%s %d %s\n", "x", FNR, $0}' file) \
<(awk '{printf "%s %d %s\n", "x", FNR, $0}' file) |
awk '$1 != $3{print $2, $4}'
```

You could fire up two process substitution instances that, each using `awk`, return the contents of the file with two synthetic fields inserted at the beginning of each record, the first field containing a fixed value (`x` in the example above) and the second field the line number.
This can then be fed to `join` stipulating field 1 as the join field. This causes every record from the first instance of the process substitution to match every record from the second. Use an `awk` post-processor to discard instances of records matching themselves (using the fact that line numbers are going to be equal in these cases)

Answer (score 0):

Create a SQLite database to join each line with each other:

```
sqlite3 tmp.db
sqlite> CREATE TABLE T (x INTEGER);
sqlite> .import input_file T
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .output output_file
sqlite> SELECT * FROM T JOIN T AS S WHERE T.x != S.x;
```

This solution does not guarantee the order of input lines, but it starts only one process, has no external loops and should work with limited RAM.

**Update:**
Fix the select statement so it will not join a value with itself. If equal values are OK as long as they are not from the same line, use `WHERE T.rowid != S.rowid`.

Answer (score 0):

Would you also consider using a totally different application, like [kdb+](http://kx.com/software-download.php)?

(its 32-bit version is free-*as-in-beer* with a 4 GB memory limit)

Some basics:

1. Loading your file as a single-column numeric list.

   ```
   flip (enlist "I";",") 0: hsym `$"/path/to/input"
   ```

   - [`0:`](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/ZeroColon) is a multi-purpose function to load from the input file. For the purpose of this question, treat `(enlist "I";",")` simply as the file format specification, and then apply a [`flip`](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/flip) to turn the output to a usable list.
2. Applying the [`cross`](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/cross) function.

   ```
   a cross a:... <from above>
   ```

   - `q` (the language of kdb+) can be quite terse, but that also means variable assignment (e.g. `a:42` to set `42` to `a`) can be assigned and used in an orderly fashion. Here, we assign our file input to a variable `a`, so that we can `cross` itself.
3. Prepare the string-ed output.

   ```
   "," 0: flip a... <from above>
   ```

   - Once again, `0:` is used to prepare the results into comma-delimited strings here.
4. Write to output file.

   ```
   (hsym `$"/path/to/output") 0: ","... <from above>
   ```

   - This time round, we need `()` around the left argument of `0:` to make the functional usage for `hsym` explicit. Finally, `0:` is used here for the *third* time to write to a file.

**Putting it all together:**

```
(hsym`$"/path/to/output")0:","0:flip a cross a:flip(enlist"I";",")0:hsym`$"/path/to/input"
```

**And now, for the bad news...**

The 4 GB RAM limitation of the 32-bit free version only handles up to about *6000 lines*...

```
q)\ts (hsym`$"output6k.txt")0:","0:flip a cross a:flip(enlist"I";",")0:hsym`$"test6k.txt"
23428 3378126736
q)count distinct flip (enlist "I";",") 0:hsym`$"test6k.txt"
6000
```

[`\ts`](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/SystemCommands#.5Cts_exp_-_time_and_space) shows that the time taken is just under 24 seconds, using up almost 3.4 GB of memory.

(*I decided to still post this as an answer, to not let my efforts go to waste...*)