# All possible permutations of words in different files in pairs

Tags: linux, command-line, text-processing, permutations

I have multiple files, let's say file1, file2 etc. Each file has one word in each line, like:

```
file1 file2 file3
one   four  six
two   five
three
```

What I want is to combine them in a new file4 in every possible permutation (without repetition) in pairs. Like

```
onetwo
onethree
onefour
onefive
...
twothree
...
onefour
...
fourone
...
```

How is this possible using Linux commands?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: no i am trying to attack a hash with John The Ripper and i need to combine different files accordingly

Comment: The files sizes are relevant.  If you replace "file*" with the actual file names, what does `wc file* | tail -n1` output?

Comment: The description says _combination_, but the "want" list also includes a _permutation_, namely: "fourone".   At present, the question is unclear.  See [combinations and permutations](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html).

Comment: I undestand, my fault, it is permutation

Comment: @agc the output is  `3362  3362 19820 total`

Comment: See also: [Command line tool to “cat” pairwise expansion of all rows in a file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169625)

Comment: Now we have enough data.  Based on the `wc`, we're not dealing with huge files, so execution speed and array size limits won't much matter in _this_ instance.  Assuming the sample output above is correct then it's a _permutation without repitition_, with "n!/(n-r)!" items.

Comment: @don_crissti, in my answer I used the shell's `set` command to hold an array of items; `set` is command line based, and is limited to a hair less than `getconf ARG_MAX` bytes, (on my system, that's about 2 megs). Since the OP's data is only 20K, (i.e. 1% of 2M), `set` is good enough.

Comment: @agc - I saw your answer but max no. of args is one thing and _array size limit_ is another thing.

Comment: @don_crissti, thanks for the distinction, perhaps _array buffer size limit_ might have been a better description.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40551/discussion-between-agc-and-don-crissti).

Comment: "Command line tool to “cat” pairwise expansion of all rows in a file" is for _permutations with repetition_; (n^r) items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
cat FILE1 FILE2 FILE3 | \
    perl -lne 'BEGIN{@a}{push @a,$_}END{foreach $x(@a){foreach $y(@a){print $x.$y}}}'
```

Output:

```
oneone
onetwo
onethree
onefour
onefive
onesix
oneseven
twoone
twotwo
twothree
twofour
twofive
twosix
twoseven
threeone
threetwo
threethree
threefour
threefive
threesix
threeseven
fourone
fourtwo
fourthree
fourfour
fourfive
foursix
fourseven
fiveone
fivetwo
fivethree
fivefour
fivefive
fivesix
fiveseven
sixone
sixtwo
sixthree
sixfour
sixfive
sixsix
sixseven
sevenone
seventwo
seventhree
sevenfour
sevenfive
sevensix
sevenseven
```

Answer (score 2):

ruby is a nice concise language for this kind of stuff

```
ruby -e '
  words = ARGV.collect {|fname| File.readlines(fname)}.flatten.map(&:chomp)
  words.combination(2).each {|pair| puts pair.join("")}
' file[123] > file4
```

```
onetwo
onethree
onefour
onefive
onesix
twothree
twofour
twofive
twosix
threefour
threefive
threesix
fourfive
foursix
fivesix
```

---

You're quite right, `combination` provides "onetwo" but misses "twoone". Good thing there's [`permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation)

```
ruby -e '
  words = ARGV.collect {|fname| File.readlines(fname)}.flatten.map(&:chomp)
  words.permutation(2).each {|pair| puts pair.join("")}
' file{1,2,3}
```

```
onetwo
onethree
onefour
onefive
onesix
twoone
twothree
twofour
twofive
twosix
threeone
threetwo
threefour
threefive
threesix
fourone
fourtwo
fourthree
fourfive
foursix
fiveone
fivetwo
fivethree
fivefour
fivesix
sixone
sixtwo
sixthree
sixfour
sixfive
```

Comment: it misses **twoone** **threeone** etc

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the total size of the input files is smaller than `getconf ARG_MAX`, (i.e. the maximum command line length), then this should work:

```
set -- $( cat file[123] )
for f in $@ ; do
    for g in $@ ; do
        [ "$f" != "$g" ] && echo $f$g
    done
done > file4
```

`cat file4` outputs:

```
onetwo
onethree
onefour
onefive
onesix
twoone
twothree
twofour
twofive
twosix
threeone
threetwo
threefour
threefive
threesix
fourone
fourtwo
fourthree
fourfive
foursix
fiveone
fivetwo
fivethree
fivefour
fivesix
sixone
sixtwo
sixthree
sixfour
sixfive
```

(As per OP clarification, the above is a revision for *permutations without repetition*. See previous draft for 
*combinations without repetition*.)

Comment: it misses **twoone** **threeone** etc

Comment: Fixed for permutations without repetition.

Answer (score 1):

A `python` solution:

```
import fileinput
from itertools import permutations
from contextlib import closing
with closing(fileinput.input(['file1', 'file2', 'file3'])) as f:
    for x, y in permutations(f, 2):
            print '{}{}'.format(x.rstrip('\n'), y.rstrip('\n'))

onetwo
onethree
onefour
onefive
onesix
twoone
twothree
twofour
twofive
twosix
threeone
threetwo
threefour
threefive
threesix
fourone
fourtwo
fourthree
fourfive
foursix
fiveone
fivetwo
fivethree
fivefour
fivesix
sixone
sixtwo
sixthree
sixfour
sixfive
```

Comment: @ iruvar this is much faster than the bash solution similar to @agc I was using.

Comment: @badner - nice - and the speed doesn't surprise me at all given that `python` file I/O and `itertools` are implemented in the C layer

Answer (score 0):

TXR Lisp:

Warmup: just get the data structure first:

```
$ txr -p '(comb (get-lines (open-files *args*)) 2)' file1 file2 file3
(("one" "two") ("one" "three") ("one" "four") ("one" "five") ("one" "six")
 ("two" "three") ("two" "four") ("two" "five") ("two" "six") ("three" "four")
 ("three" "five") ("three" "six") ("four" "five") ("four" "six")
 ("five" "six"))
```

Now just a matter of getting the right output format. If we catenate the pairs together and then use `tprint` (implicitly via the `-t` option), we are there.

First, the catenation via mapping through `cat-str`:

```
$ txr -p '[mapcar cat-str (comb (get-lines (open-files *args*)) 2)]' file1 file2 file3
("onetwo" "onethree" "onefour" "onefive" "onesix" "twothree" "twofour"
 "twofive" "twosix" "threefour" "threefive" "threesix" "fourfive"
 "foursix" "fivesix")
```

OK, we have the right data. Now just use `tprint` function (`-t`) instead of `prinl` (`-p`):

```
$ txr -t '[mapcar cat-str (comb (get-lines (open-files *args*)) 2)]' file1 file2 file3
onetwo
onethree
onefour
onefive
onesix
twothree
twofour
twofive
twosix
threefour
threefive
threesix
fourfive
foursix
fivesix
```

Finally, we read the question again and do permutations instead of combinations with `perm` rather than `comb`, as required:

```
$ txr -t '[mapcar cat-str (perm (get-lines (open-files *args*)) 2)]' file1 file2 file3
onetwo
onethree
onefour
onefive
onesix
twoone
twothree
twofour
twofive
twosix
threeone
threetwo
threefour
threefive
threesix
fourone
fourtwo
fourthree
fourfive
foursix
fiveone
fivetwo
fivethree
fivefour
fivesix
sixone
sixtwo
sixthree
sixfour
sixfive
```