# grep files from list

Tags: bash, grep, command-substitution, process-substitution

I am trying to run grep against a list of a few hundred files:

```
$ head -n 3 <(cat files.txt)
admin.php
ajax/accept.php
ajax/add_note.php
```

However, even though I am grepping for a string that I know is found in the files, the following does not search the files:

```
$ grep -i 'foo' <(cat files.txt)

$ grep -i 'foo' admin.php
The foo was found
```

I am familiar with the `-f` flag which will read the *patterns* from a file. But how to read the *input files*?

I had considered the horrible workaround of copying the files to a temporary directory as `cp` seems to support the `<(cat files.txt)` format, and from there grepping the files. **Shirley there is a better way.**

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You seem to be grepping the list of filenames, not the files themselves. `<(cat files.txt)` just lists the files. Try `<(cat $(cat files.txt))` to actually concatenate them and search them as a single stream, or

```
grep -i 'foo' $(cat files.txt)
```

to give grep all the files.

However, if there are too many files on the list, you may have problems with number of arguments. In that case I'd just write

```
while read filename; do grep -Hi 'foo' "$filename"; done < files.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize that `while` could receive the lines of file.txt as such.

Comment: You'll want to disable the _glob_ part of that _split+glob_ operator here (unless the shell is zsh).

Comment: `while` isn't exactly receiving the lines from the file, `read` is doing that;`while` just lets us do that in a loop. The loop ends when `read` fails (i.e. returns a non-zero return code), normally due to the End Of File being reached.

Comment: To read a (text) line, the syntax is `IFS= read -r filename`, `read filename` is something else.

Comment: Note that `-H` is a GNU extension. You're missing some `--`.

Comment: @dotancohen: For more info on `read -r` see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18886/88378 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87301/88378

Answer (score 11):

```
xargs grep -i -- foo /dev/null < files.txt
```

assuming files are blank or newline delimited (where quotes or backslashes can be used to escape those separators). With GNU `xargs` you can specify the delimiter with `-d` (which then disables the quoting handling though).

```
(unset -v IFS; set -f; grep -i -- foo $(cat files.txt))
```

assuming files are space, tab or newline separated (no way to escape those though you can choose a different separator by assigning it to `IFS`). That one will fail if the file list is too big on most systems.

Those also assume that none of the files are called `-`.

Comment: It is better/faster to use `$(< file)` instead of `$(cat file)`, at least in `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: for limited files number $(anything) is ok, but remember. this expands command line. for many files it will exceed this one. For that situation only xargs will do properly, because it can split files into sensible groups.  btw. of course, $(< file) works better, because you ommit unnesesary `cat` call. Unfortunately saving is extremaly little.

Answer (score 9):

To read a list of file names from stdin you can use `xargs`. E.g.,

```
cat files.txt | xargs -d'\n' grep -i -- 'foo'
```

By default, `xargs` reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks. The `-d'\n'` tells it to use newline as the argument delimiter, so it can handle file names containing blanks. (As Stéphane Chazelas points out, that's a GNU extension). However, it won't cope with file names containing newlines; we'd need a slightly more complicated approach to handle those.

FWIW, this approach is somewhat faster than a `while read` loop, as bash's `read` command is very slow - it reads its data character by character, whereas `xargs` reads its input more efficiently. Also, `xargs` only invokes the `grep` command as many times as it needs to, with each invocation receiving multiple file names, and that's more efficient than invoking `grep` individually for each file name.

See the [xargs man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) and the xargs info page for further details.

Comment: this is traditional use, when file list is separated by new line char. then `-d'\n'` is not usable in this context. But if file names contains special characters and or new lines, consider use null char separator. It is supported by `find` and `xargs` commands.

Answer (score 6):

`xargs` can read items from a file (like your `files.txt` list) with it's option:

```
   --arg-file=file
   -a file
          Read items from file instead of standard input.  If you use this
          option, stdin remains unchanged when commands are  run.   Other‐
          wise, stdin is redirected from /dev/null.
```

So this should work too:

```
xargs -a files.txt grep -i 'foo'
```

or for spaces in filenames

```
xargs -d'\n' -a files.txt grep -i 'foo'
xargs -I{} -a files.txt grep -i 'foo' {}
```