# How do I trim leading and trailing whitespace from each line of some output?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, pipe, whitespace

I would like to remove all leading and trailing spaces and tabs from each line in an output.

Is there a simple tool like `trim` I could pipe my output into?

Example file:

```
test space at back 
 test space at front
TAB at end  
    TAB at front
sequence of some    space in the middle
some empty lines with differing TABS and spaces:





 test space at both ends
```

Comment: To anyone looking here for a solution to remove newlines, that is a different problem.  By definition a newline creates a new line of text.  Therefore a line of text cannot contain a newline.  The question you want to ask is how to remove a newline from the beginning or end of a string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369758, or how to remove blank lines or lines that are just whitespace: https://serverfault.com/questions/252921

Answer (score 485, accepted):

```
awk '{$1=$1;print}'
```

or shorter:

```
awk '{$1=$1};1'
```

Would trim leading and trailing space or tab characters<sup>1</sup> ***and also*** squeeze sequences of tabs and spaces into a single space.

That works because when you assign something to any one  *field* and then try to access the whole record (`$0`, the thing `print` prints be default), `awk` needs to rebuild that record by joining all fields (`$1`, ..., `$NF`) with `OFS` (space by default).

To also remove blank lines, change it to `awk 'NF{$1=$1;print}'` (where `NF` as a condition selects the records for which the `N`umber of `F`ields is non-zero). Do **not** do <strike>`awk '$1=$1'`</strike> as sometimes suggested as that would also remove lines whose first field is any representation of `0` supported by `awk` (`0`, `00`, `-0e+12`...)

---

<sub>¹ and possibly other blank characters depending on the locale and the `awk` implementation</sub>

Comment: Semicolon on second example is superfluous.  Could use: `awk '{$1=$1}1'`

Comment: @Brian, [no, the `;` is required in the standard awk syntax](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=226#c2226)

Comment: Interesting...  No semicolon is supported by gawk, mawk and OS X's awk.  (At least for my versions (1.2, 4.1.1, and 20070501, respectively)

Comment: Although, even though gawk supports it, it confirms the semicolon usage with: `Multiple  statements  may  be  put on one line by separating them with a ";".  This applies to both the statements within the action part of a pattern-action pair (the usual case), and to the pattern-action statements themselves.`

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this approach is that you lose repeating spaces within the line. For example, `echo -e 'foo    \t     bar' | awk '{$1=$1};1'`

Comment: `echo '    hello   ' | xargs`

Comment: In my special context. (Called in SQilte CLI `.shell` comand). It was not working. But the SED solution was OK.

Comment: How do I do this recursively?

Comment: How can I turn this into an alias in bash?  I tried but receiving errors

Comment: @ctrlbrk I'm not sure an alias is what you need. Might be better to create a custom bash script called `trim` and add it to your path. Then you could do `??? | trim`.

Comment: I have looked for something like this literally for years! Thanks!

Comment: `$ awk '{1.txt=1.txt};1'` leads to `awk: cmd. line:1: {1.txt=1.txt};1` `awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ syntax error`. How to fix?

Comment: @pmor, the file or stream to process must be fed as input to `awk`. Like with `awk '{$1=$1};1' < 1.txt` or `awk '{$1=$1};1' 1.txt`.

Comment: Since which version of `awk` should the command `awk '{$1=$1;print}'` work correctly?

Comment: Simple, straight to the point! Nice one :)

Comment: Not the OP's use-case but, where the _line_ is supposed to be just one _word_ without any enclosing whitespace (a branch name on a pipeline) I used a simpler `awk '{ print $1 }'` - what am I missing?

Comment: To also remove blank lines awk '{$1=$1;NF}'   fails. You must use **awk '{$1=$1};NF>1'**. This is because $1=$1 creates an empty but existent field. You can test this by **printf "aaa\n\nbbb\n" | awk '{$1=$1; print NR,NF,$0}'**

Comment: Thanks @user9101329, I've changed it to `NF{$1=$1;print}` as `{$1=$1};NF>1` would also remove the lines with one non empty sequence of non-blank characters.

Answer (score 115):

The command can be condensed like so if you're using GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' < file
```

#### Example

Here's the above command in action.

```
$ echo -e " \t   blahblah  \t  " | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//'
blahblah
```

You can use `hexdump` to confirm that the `sed` command is stripping the desired characters correctly.

```
$ echo -e " \t   blahblah  \t  " | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' | hexdump -C
00000000  62 6c 61 68 62 6c 61 68  0a                       |blahblah.|
00000009
```

#### Character classes

You can also use character class names instead of literally listing the sets like this, `[ \t]`:

```
$ sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//' < file
```

#### Example

```
$ echo -e " \t   blahblah  \t  " | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//'
```

Most of the GNU tools that make use of regular expressions (regex) support these classes (here with their equivalent in the typical C locale of an ASCII-based system (and there only)).

```
 [[:alnum:]]  - [A-Za-z0-9]     Alphanumeric characters
 [[:alpha:]]  - [A-Za-z]        Alphabetic characters
 [[:blank:]]  - [ \t]           Space or tab characters only
 [[:cntrl:]]  - [\x00-\x1F\x7F] Control characters
 [[:digit:]]  - [0-9]           Numeric characters
 [[:graph:]]  - [!-~]           Printable and visible characters
 [[:lower:]]  - [a-z]           Lower-case alphabetic characters
 [[:print:]]  - [ -~]           Printable (non-Control) characters
 [[:punct:]]  - [!-/:-@[-`{-~]  Punctuation characters
 [[:space:]]  - [ \t\v\f\n\r]   All whitespace chars
 [[:upper:]]  - [A-Z]           Upper-case alphabetic characters
 [[:xdigit:]] - [0-9a-fA-F]     Hexadecimal digit characters
```

Using these instead of literal sets always seems like a waste of space, but if you're concerned with your code being portable, or having to deal with alternative character sets (think international), then you'll likely want to use the class names instead.

#### References

- [Section 3 of the sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html)

Comment: Note that `[[:space:]]` is not equivalent to `[ \t]` in the general case (unicode, etc). `[[:space:]]` will probably be much slower (as there are many more types of whitespaces in unicode than just `' '` and `'\t'`). Same thing for all the others.

Comment: `sed 's/^[ \t]*//'` is not portable. Atually POSIX even requires that to remove a sequence of space, backslash or `t` characters, and that's what GNU `sed` also does when `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment.

Comment: What if I want to trim newlines characters?
'\n
\n
text
\n
\n'

Comment: I like the sed solution because of the lack of other side-affects as in the awk solution.  The first variation does not work when I tried it in bash on OSX jsut now, but the character class version does work:
`sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//'`

Comment: @EugeneBiryukov see my comment on the original post

Comment: instead of `[ \t]*` why don't you use **`\s*`** to catch all white-spaces ?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work if there is a tab in the begging of a line.

Comment: Can someone explain why `s,^[[:space:]]*,,` works, but `s,^[[:space:]]+,,` does not?

Comment: @MichaelK escaping that `+` works - `s,^[[:space:]]\+,,`. If you tell `sed` to do extended regex, `-r` it'll work w/ `sed -r 's,^[[:space:]]+,,'`. BTW I typically pipe this to `cat -A` to see  the output more clearly.

Answer (score 68):

xargs without arguments do that.

Example:

```
trimmed_string=$(echo "no_trimmed_string" | xargs)
```

Comment: This also contracts multiple spaces within a line, which was not requested in the question

Comment: @roaima - true but the accepted answer also squeezes spaces (which was not requested in the question). I think the real problem here is that `xargs` will fail to deliver if the input contains backslashes and single quotes.

Comment: @don_crissti that doesn't mean the accepted answer correctly answers the question as asked, though. But in this case here it wasn't flagged as a caveat whereas in the accepted answer it was. I've hopefully highlighted the fact in case it's of relevance to a future reader.

Comment: It also breaks on single quotes, double quotes, backslash characters. It also runs one or more `echo` invocations. Some echo implementations will also process options and/or backslashes... That also only works for single-line input.

Comment: This is a clever (unorthodox) answer! I agree w/ @StéphaneChazelas, essentially invoking the default `xargs /bin/echo` command.

Comment: I know this has shortcomings, but if you want something simple, with known-restricted input, this is beautifully succinct in 5 chars... Obtuse perhaps, but succinct!

Comment: for multi-line inputs you can `<multi-line> | xargs -L1`

Comment: This treats backslashes improperly and may break in shells like Bash as they extended `echo` with options etc. Also not suit OP's needs as it works on single line.

Answer (score 41):

As suggested by **Stéphane Chazelas** in the accepted answer, you can now
create a script `/usr/local/bin/trim`:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{$1=$1};1'
```

and give that file executable rights:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/trim
```

Now you can pass every output to `trim` for example:

```
cat file | trim
```

---

*(for the comments below: i used this before: `while read i; do echo "$i"; done`

 which also works fine, but is less performant)*

Comment: Good luck if your file is huge and/or contains backslashes.

Comment: @don_crissti: could you comment a bit more?, which solution would be better fitting for huge files, and how could I modify my solution if the file contained backslashes?

Comment: You'll have to use `while read -r line` to preserve backslashes and [even then...](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176490/echoing-stdin-when-running-an-ed1-script/176514#comment292069_176502). As to huge files / speed, really, you picked the worst solution. I don't think there's anything worse out there. See the answers on [Why is using a shell loop to process text bad practice ?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) including my comment on the last answer where I added a link to a speed benchmark. The `sed` answers here are perfectly fine IMO and far better than `read`.

Comment: @don_crissti ...and/or has lines starting with `-` and followed by combinations of 1 or more e, E or n characters, and/or contains NUL characters. Also, a non-terminated line after the last newline will be skipped.

Comment: You can also add an alias in /etc/profile (or your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc etc...) alias trim="awk '{\$1=\$1};1'"

Comment: No need for `bash`, you can make it `#! /usr/bin/awk -f` `{$1=$1};1`. (beware of file names containing `=` characters though)

Comment: note that it  has to be on 2 lines, one for the she-bang, one for the code  (`{$1=$1};1`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: That doesn't seem to work. Please post it as a whole new answer, so we can see the line breaks as you intended. And we can discuss then if it works. (you mean a she-bang with just `#!` ?)

Comment: awk didn't work for me, still untrimmed spaces

Comment: Would this work as an alias, or would it be better as a function defined in /etc/profile?

Comment: How do I use this to trim files in-place?

Comment: On Solaris awk doesn't work, you need gawk.

Comment: I'm using zshell and found it very convient declcare a function such as:

  function trim() {
      awk '{$1=$1};1'
   }

No need for file.

Answer (score 36):

If you store lines as variables, you can use bash to do the job:

## remove leading whitespace from a string:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' "${text##+([[:space:]])}"
```

## remove trailing whitespace from a string:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' "${text%%+([[:space:]])}"
```

## remove all whitespace from a string:

```
printf '%s\n' "${text//[[:space:]]}"
```

Comment: Removing all white-space from a string is not same as removing both leading and trailing spaces (as in question).

Comment: Far the best solution - it requires only bash builtins and no external process forks.

Comment: Nice.  Scripts run a LOT faster if they don't have to pull in outside programs (such as awk or sed).  This works with "modern" (93u+) versions of ksh, as well.

Comment: Upon testing, your `ltrim` and `rtrm` solutions do not work because they are too greedy. Given a string such as `  \n\n\n\v\f\t\t\r\r       Anthony Rutledge.   \n\r\v\\f\n\n\n\t\t\t   `, your solutions will wipe away the entire string.

Answer (score 32):

To remove all leading and trailing spaces from a given line thanks to a 'piped' tool, I can identify 3 different ways which are not completely equivalent. These differences concern the spaces between words of the input line. Depending on the expected behaviour, you'll make your choice.

## Examples

To explain the differences, let consider this dummy input line:

```
"   \t  A   \tB\tC   \t  "
```

### tr

```
$ echo -e "   \t  A   \tB\tC   \t  " | tr -d "[:blank:]"
ABC
```

`tr` is really a simple command. In this case, it deletes any space or tabulation character.

### awk

```
$ echo -e "   \t  A   \tB\tC   \t  " | awk '{$1=$1};1'
A B C
```

`awk` deletes leading and tailing spaces and squeezes to a single space every spaces between words.

### sed

```
$ echo -e "   \t  A   \tB\tC   \t  " | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//'
A       B   C
```

In this case, `sed` deletes leading and tailing spaces without touching any spaces between words.

**Remark:**

In the case of one word per line, `tr` does the job.

Comment: None of this trims trailing/leading newlines though

Comment: +1 for a list of solutions with their (sometimes unexpected) output.

Comment: @user61382 this is rather late, but see my comment on the original post.

Comment: @highmaintenance : use `[:space:]`, instead of [:blank:], for the command `tr`, like: `... | tr -d [:space:]`, to remove newlines too. (see: `man tr`)

Answer (score 26):

```
sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
```

If you're reading a line into a shell variable, `read` does that already [unless instructed otherwise](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18922/in-while-ifs-read-why-does-ifs-have-no-effect).

Comment: +1 for `read`. So if you pipe to while read it works: `cat file  | while read i; do echo $i; done`

Comment: @rubo except that in your example the unquoted variable is also reprocessed by the shell. Use `echo "$i"` to see the true effect of the `read`

Answer (score 11):

An answer you can understand in a glance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
for line in sys.stdin: print(line.strip())
```

Bonus: replace [`str.strip([chars])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) with arbitrary characters to trim or use `.lstrip()` or `.rstrip()` as needed.

Like [rubo77's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102229/171025), save as script `/usr/local/bin/trim` and give permissions with `chmod +x`.

Comment: I'm not normally a fan of python in my scripts but this is by far one of the most legible scripts in comparison to all the other incantations in these answers.

Answer (score 9):

sed is a great tool for that:

```
                        # substitute ("s/")
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//; # parts of lines that start ("^")  with a space/tab 
     s/[[:blank:]]*$//' # or end ("$") with a space/tab
                        # with nothing (/)
```

You can use it for your case be either piping in the text, e.g.

```
<file sed -e 's/^[[...
```

or by acting on it 'inline' if your `sed` is the GNU one:

```
sed -i 's/...' file
```

but changing the source this way is "dangerous" as it may be unrecoverable when it doesn't work right (or even when it does!), so backup first (or use `-i.bak` which also has the benefit to be portable to some BSD `sed`s)!

Answer (score 7):

You will be adding this to your little Bash library. I can almost bet on it!
This has the benefit of *not adding a newline character to the end of your output*, as will happen with `echo` throwing off your expected output. Moreover, these solutions are reusable, do not require modifying the shell options, can be called in-line with your pipelines, and are posix compliant. This is the best answer, by far. Modify to your liking.

Output tested with `od -cb`, something some of the other solutions might want to do with their output.

BTW: The correct quantifier is the `+`, not the `*`, as you want the replacement to be triggered upon 1 or more whitespace characters!

### ltrim (that you can pipe input into)

```
function ltrim ()
{
    sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+//'
}
```

### rtrim (that you can pipe input into)

```
function rtrim ()
{
    sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+$//'
}
```

### trim (the best of both worlds and yes, you can pipe to it)

```
function trim ()
{
    ltrim | rtrim
}
```

**Update**: I have improved this solution to use bash native constructs. The Stream Editor (sed) is not required. You can use shell expansions to achieve what you want, and it works better than the sed solution!

[Bash Reference Manual -- Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions)

Answer (score 4):

If the string one is trying to trim is short and continuous/contiguous, one can simply pass it as a parameter to any bash function:

```
    trim(){
        echo $@
    }

    a="     some random string   "

    echo ">>`trim $a`<<"
Output
>>some random string<<
```

Answer (score 4):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6):**

```
raku -ne '.trim.put;'
```

Or more simply:

```
raku -pe '.=trim;'
```

As a previous answer suggests (thanks, @Jeff_Clayton!), you can create a `trim` alias in your bash environment:

```
alias trim="raku -pe '.=trim;'"
```

Finally, to only remove leading/trailing whitespace (e.g. unwanted indentation), you can use the appropriate `trim-leading` or `trim-trailing` command instead.

https://raku.org/

Answer (score 3):

translate command would work

```
cat file | tr -d [:blank:]
```

Comment: This command is not correct as it removes _**all**_ spaces from the file, not just leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: @BrianRedbeard You are correct. This is still a useful answer for a monolithic string, without spaces.

Comment: You might call this `stripper` instead of some kind of trim. :-)

Comment: I completely agree w/ @AnthonyRutledge. Not everyone (perhaps **no one**) actually winds up here - 11 years after the OP - with the same exact problem as stated in the OP!!  It's disappointing to me to see 4 downvotes to this answer as it has utility to many of us who wind up here via various *"search terms"* like I used: `bash cut spaces from start of string`.  A pox on you [*plutonian*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/plutonian) [*supercilious*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/supercilious) downvoters - you're disgusting.

Comment: @Seamus You can use shell expansions to achieve what you want, and it works better than a `sed` solution, or one that uses `tr`!  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions

Answer (score 3):

```
trimpy () {
    python3 -c 'import sys
for line in sys.stdin: print(line.strip())'
}
trimsed () {
gsed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
}
trimzsh () {
   local out="$(</dev/stdin)"
   [[ "$out" =~ '^\s*(.*\S)\s*$' ]] && out="$match[1]"  || out=''
   print -nr -- "$out"
}
# example usage
echo " hi " | trimpy
```

Bonus: replace `str.strip([chars])` with arbitrary characters to trim or use `.lstrip()` or `.rstrip()` as needed.

Comment: Did you just copy my answer for python? Attribution would be nice...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this shell function using awk

```
awkcliptor(){
    awk -e 'BEGIN{ RS="^$" } {gsub(/^[\n\t ]*|[\n\t ]*$/,"");print ;exit}' "$1" ; }
```

`BEGIN{ RS="^$" }`:
in the beginning before start parsing set record
separator to none i.e. treat the whole input as
a single record

`gsub(this,that)`:
substitute this regexp with that string

`/^[\n\t ]*|[\n\t ]*$/`:
of that string catch any pre newline space and tab class
or post newline space and tab class and replace them with
empty string

`print;exit`:
then print and exit

`"$1"`:
and pass the first argument of the function to be
process by awk

how to use:
copy above code , paste in shell, and then enter to
define the function.
then you can use awkcliptor as a command with first  argument as the input file

sample usage:

```
echo '
 ggggg    

      ' > a_file
awkcliptor a_file
```

output:

```
ggggg
```

or

```
echo -e "\n ggggg    \n\n      "|awkcliptor
```

output:

```
ggggg
```

Comment: Can you please explain the difference to just `awk '{$1=$1};1'` ?

Answer (score 1):

For those of us without enough space in the brain to remember obscure sed syntax, just reverse the string, cut the 1st field with a delimiter of space, and reverse it back again.

```
cat file | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
```

Comment: This only works if there is no more than one space leading each line and no more than one word in any line.

Comment: Another way to do it with cut: `echo "$mystring" | cut -d " " -f 2-`

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is using perl: `perl -n -e'/[\s]*(.*)?[\s]*/ms && print $1'`

Take for example:

```bash
MY_SPACED_STRING="\n\n   my\nmulti-line\nstring  \n\n"

echo $MY_SPACED_STRING
```

Would output:

```
   my
multi-line
string
```

Then:

```bash
echo $MY_SPACED_STRING | perl -n -e'/[\s]*(.*)?[\s]*/ms && print $1'
```

Would output:

```
my
multi-line
string
```

Answer (score 0):

for bash example:

```
alias trim="awk '{\$1=\$1};1'"
```

usage:

```
echo -e  "    hello\t\tkitty   " | trim | hexdump  -C
```

result:

```
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 6b 69  74 74 79 0a              |hello kitty.|
0000000c
```

Comment: The `awk '{$1=$1};1'` answer was given long ago.  The idea of making an alias out of it was suggested in a comment almost as long ago.  Yes, you are allowed to take somebody else’s comment and turn it into an answer.  But, if you do, you should give credit to the people who posted the idea before you.  And this is such a trivial extension of the accepted answer that it’s not really worth the bother.

Comment: Idea was to make alias. I doesn't seen that answer before.

Comment: and second thing from stack:

"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0):

Remove start space and tab and end space and tab:

```bsh
alias strip='python3 -c "from sys import argv; print(argv[1].strip(\" \").strip(\"\t\"))"'
```

Remove every space and tab

```bsh
alias strip='python3 -c "from sys import argv; print(argv[1].replace(\"\t\", \"\").replace(\" \", \"\")"'
```

Give argument to strip. Use sys.stdin().read() to make pipeable instead of argv.

Answer (score 0):

simple enough for my purposes was this:

```
_text_="    one    two       three         "

echo "$_text_" | { read __ ; echo ."$__". ; }
```

... giving ...

```
.one    two       three.
```

... if you want to squeeze the spaces then ...

```
echo .$( echo $_text_ ).
```

... gives ...

```
.one two three.
```

Answer (score 0):

rust sd command
`sd '^\s*(.*)\s*' '$1'`