# Echoing stdin when running an ed(1) script

Tags: shell, stdin, ed

Given the following `ed` script,

```
$ cat helloworld
a
hello
world
.
,n
,s,o,O,g
,n
Q
```

I would like to obtain somehow the interactive output

```
$ ed
a
hello
world
.
,n
1   hello
2   world
,s,o,O,g
,n
1   hellO
2   wOrld
Q
$
```

instead of the expected

```
$ cat helloworld | ed
1   hello
2   world
1   hellO
2   wOrld
$
```

Is that possible, maybe using a third-party utility? Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I guess I should add some motivation. I would like to produce some sample ed sessions, and probably save them with `script(1)`. If this process is performed "live", any modifications would basically imply typing the whole tutorial again (bad) or alternatively "figuring out" the output, potentially based on a long editing session (worse).

Comment: `ed` reads from `STDIN` by default and provides the ouput that you want.  Just write your input text directly into `ed`.

Comment: Thanks, Alexej. I've added some context in my edit to justify my goal. It may very well not be easily doable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after monkeying around with it, this is what I'd use:

```
 awk '{ print; system("sleep 0") }' edscript | tee /dev/tty | ed
```

or, without `tee`:

```
awk '{ print >"/dev/stderr"; print | "ed"; system("sleep 0") }' edscript
```

If `print >"/dev/stderr"` doesn't work on your system you could use `print | "cat >&2"`.

---

With `gnu sed`:

```
sed -u -n -e 'p;w /dev/stderr' -e 's|.*||e' edscript | ed
```

---

Another way that works just as well:
Use `split` to split your *edscript* on each line:

```
split -l1 edscript
```

this will produce pieces like `xaa`, `xab`...`xah`.
You could then use the pieces like this:

```
for i in x*; do awk '{ print >"/dev/stderr"; print }' $i; done | ed
```

or

```
for i in x*; do sed -n -e 'p;w /dev/stderr' $i; done | ed
```

to get the expected result. Then you `rm x*`...

Comment: Thanks for your answer*s*! If I understand correctly the last approach is exclusively pedagogic, as it is longer, involves splitting the script, and has the line/pattern addressing issue which is not present in the first two solutions. (Right?)

Comment: Thanks again, Don. (Sorry for the name update in the middle of this thread.) I guess your second method can become way simpler by running `rm x*` first and then simply `for i in x*; do cat $x | tee /dev/tty; done | ed`. I will probably feel most comfortable adapting Mark's answer with `printf '%s\n' "$line"` instead of `echo "$line"`, removing `IFS=` as there's only one variable and changing `sleep 0.5` to `sleep 0` (noticing the many options you said I would have). I learned a lot with your feedback! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again! Now I see why `IFS=` is there, even if the whole line is to be read into a single variable. Some information may be lost. Unlikely in this case, but nice to know this best practice. If I may ask, did you pick all of this up "by doing and learning", or was there a single source/book that you followed carefully and would suggest. Thanks once more! Happy 2015!

Comment: [Meta-question: for some reason my "at"+"your username" doesn't stick. Maybe because I asked the question?] I forgot about `split(1)`. Yes, I'd be inclined to delete all files beginning with x, maybe in a temporary directory. I'm pretty sure `split(1)` generates file names in alphabetical order, so that `cat $x*` gives you back the original file. I've used it in that basic way a few times. The UNIX founders got a lot of things right!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to simulate an interactive terminal session, in which the user types a command, waits for a response (or, given that the target is `ed`, *sometimes* waits for a response), then types another command, etc. You could write an `expect` script to do this, but it may be good enough to just send a line at a time to both the terminal and the target process, with a brief pause between each line.

```
    $ while IFS= read -r line
      do
        printf '%s\n' "$line" >/dev/tty
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
        sleep 0.5
      done < helloworld | ed
a
hello
world
.
,n
1   hello
2   world
,s,o,O,g
,n
1   hellO
2   wOrld
Q
```

To better distinguish input from output, you could add color or other highlighting to the 
`echo "$line" >/dev/tty` line, or, in this particular case, enable the prompt character in `ed` (the `P` command) so that a `*` will show up in front of each `ed` command.

Comment: @don_crissti Thank you. I've updated the answer to include your fix.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Although I could follow your approach more easily, I went with Don's solutions as they turn out to be more portable. It turns out `read -r` doesn't really capture a raw line everywhere, or at least not in OpenBSD ("\\" becomes "\", much to my puzzlement!).

One more note: running Don's scripts it looks like `sleep 0.5` is way too cautious, as it can be in fact lowered to `sleep 0`.

Comment: @eze Glad you found a good solution. Shell scripting, as in my answer, sometimes results in adequate, but not optimal, solutions.

Comment: In case anybody likes this solution, use `printf '%s\n' "$line"` instead of `echo "$line"` for greater portability.

Comment: @ezequiel-garzon Thanks. I've changed the echos to printfs.

Answer (score 3):

I did something... complicated. I've been looking into `ex`/`ed` recently - I'm not very good with either - and this marked an opportunity to dive a little deeper. This parses the `ed` script first and passes it off to `ed` in-stream:

```
b='[:blank:]'
sed -e 'h;/\n/!i\' -e 0i -e 's/^\(.*[^\]\)*\(\\\\\)*\\$//;tn'"
/^\n*\([0-9;$,.$b]*[gGvV].*\\\\\n[$b]*\)*\([0-9,$.;${b}]*[aic][$b]*\)\
\(\n\(.*\)\n\.\)*\(\n.*\)*$/{ s//\4/;:n" -e 'G;//{N;D
    };g;s//\1\2/;l;x;s//\4/;l;H;s/.*/./;a\' -e '.
};l;g;i\' -e .\\ -e 1,.p\\ -e u <ed_script | ed
```

It is less complicated then before - and now virtually all of the complication lies in a single regex spanning two lines. That one long regex handles virtually all of the testing for the entire script.

The idea is that, as near as I can tell, you can only get to *insert* mode with one of either the `a`ppend, `i`nsert, or `c`hange commands. *insert* mode then takes all input literally up to the next occurring line consisting of only a `.` dot. Any other continued command that spans multiple lines - even a sequence of such where `G`, `g`, `V`, or `v` are involved - is necessarily continued to the next line with a trailing `\`backslash - though, as usual, a `\`backslash escapes itself in that context.

So, while it's entirely possible I'm mistaken, I *think* this handles all cases. For every input line that doesn't match a `[aic]` ...  `.` dot series `sed` inserts a series of commands that looks like:

```
0i
command-line$
.
1,.p
u
```

...instructing `ed` to `i`nsert an unequivocal `l`ook *(as written by `sed`)* at its own command, then to `p`rint it, and last to `u`ndo the whole operation - which has the very convenient result of getting the edit done, printing it, reversing it, *and* restoring the last address in a single action.

For those that lines that *do* match in a sequence of either trailing backslashes or an `[aic]` ... `.` series it is a little more complicated. In those cases `sed` recursively pulls them in until it encounters the end of the series before doing its `l`ook. I was careful to separate the `[aic]`, `.`, and actual literal input into separate prints - each of those types will get its own `l`ook - such that the literal input is strung together as much as possible *(`sed` will break a `l`ook output at 80 chars by default)*.

I guess it's easier just to show you. You'll notice the `?` prompt below - this occurs because the `g` command given before it is not valid command - not because `sed` mangles the input *(I hope)*. Here is the output from a modified version of your example dataset:

```
g \\\n  a$
hello\nworld\\\n\n  0a\n  world\\\nworld\nworld$
.$
?
,n$
1       hello
2       world\
3
4         0a
5         world\
6       world
7       world
,s,o,O,g$
4$
  0a
.,$n$
4         0a
5         wOrld\
6       wOrld
7       wOrld
,s,$,\\\n\\\n\\\\$
\
,n$
1       hellO
2
3       \
4       wOrld\
5
6       \
7
8
9       \
10        0a
11
12      \
13        wOrld\
14
15      \
16      wOrld
17
18      \
19      wOrld
20
21      \
Q$
```

Comment: Wow! That looks hard to debug, let alone understand in my case... Moreover, the output is not quite what I described. Thanks for your input in any event!

Comment: @don_crissti - thanks Don. Hmmm... I thought I handled that by adding the `/\n/!s/$/ \\/` part which is *supposed* to ensure that any line within one of those blocks never gets a doubled up \\ at the end. Or do I defeat my own purpose there? Now I forget... probably ezequiel makes a good point. This is just experimentation... I want to do a readline type of thing *without* readline - which does not at all suit my tastes - and I think `vi/ex/ed` are probably my best bets. Try `stty raw isig onlret opost min 1 time 0; dd bs=8 conv=sync </dev/tty | sed -nzue /./l`... Now to get that into `ex`...

Comment: @don_crissti - oh, wait. I see why it breaks for those... I e`x`change at the end of the completed `[aic]` test and again *after* testing for `...\\\(\n.*\)*$` that e`x`change needs to change - I did it like that because I wanted to alternate correctly between `h`old pattern spaces depending on whether I had just gathered \\escaped input or `[aic]` input. In the former case the data I want at the end is in `h`old space when I'm through verifying it, but in the latter case it's in pattern space. I just need to rearrange that a little bit and the `[aic]` block won't test positive for `\\\n`.

Comment: @don_crissti - I pretty much rewrote it, I guess. It's here now if you wanna play around with it.

Comment: @don_crissti - what's it doing there? `s/.*//e`? It seems... weird. Pretty much though if you just use `w /dev/fd/2` you've moved from relying on a single `sed` implementation to a system that supports `/dev/fd/[num]` links. They tend to be a little more portable by number. Also fun is `4<<SED\n$(sed '... w /dev/fd/4' >/dev/null 2>&1\nSED\n`

Comment: @don_crissti - are you using that `e` to do complete writes? Because when the shell it runs up and kills immediately opens() and closes() its output on that pipe it should look like a write to the pipe, right?

Comment: @don_crissti - I'm playing around with it - and it's pretty cool - but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: @don_crissti - I would think maybe `dd` could be used to limit bytes per write... I once did something where I made a shell `kill -PIPE $$` itself for every iteration of a loop with a trap where it would consistently `exec 3>&1  >&-; exec >&3` so it would keep reopening the pipe for every write. I never made anything useful of it, because I was never able to figure out for sure why it worked - was it the `kill ... trap` stuff or was it the `exec ...` stuff? Or both? I still don't know, and so I'm not sure how your thing works. I wish I could upvote it again, though.

Comment: @mikeserv, +1 for being a mad genius :P