# How to use cut to trim the first x variable spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, cut

I have a file that is like this:

```
              67 lol
             143 hi
              21 test
               1 ciao
               5 lo
```

I want to remove the spaces.

```
67 lol
143 hi
21 test
1 ciao
5 lo
```

I know that I can use sed to do that, for example with:

```
cat ciao | sed 's/[[:space:]]*\([[:digit:]]* .*\)/\1/' | sort -g
```

but my professor says that I can easily use cut to do that... but I really don't know how.

Something like this:

```
cat ciao | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
```

would not work because I lose the number information.
lol
hi
test
ciao
lo

Comment: I doubt that the professor is right: `cut` can remove a fixed number of spaces only.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71380920/how-to-use-cut-to-trim-the-first-x-variable-spaces

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I trim leading and trailing whitespace from each line of some output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102008/how-do-i-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-from-each-line-of-some-output)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nope, because I also need the numbers, and that way I erase the numbers :/

Comment: I have found an answer myself: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/693283/314643

Answer (score 1):

If your file had a tab and not spaces, you could use `cut` only:

```
cut -f2- < file
```

With spaces, `cut` is not enough, but you can use a combination of `tr` and `cut`:

```
tr -s ' ' < file | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I wanted to only use cut though. I found an answer, if you are interested: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/693283/314643

Comment: "I wanted to only use `cut` only" and posts an answer that uses (a useless use of) `cat`, 2x `rev` and `cut`. I bet, `tr` + `cut` performs better.

Comment: @Allexj You can't use only `cut` to remove a variable amount of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer:
I can do this:

```
cat ciao | rev | cut -d ' ' -f 1,2 | rev
```

to not lose the number information. works!

Comment: You will find that this fails if a line has more than the expected number of space-delimited words.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that until your professor shows code that works, they may not know what they are talking about. The `cut` utility is a tool for extracting columns delimited by some single character. Your data is not that.

If all you want is to remove any spaces at the start of lines, then the following `sed` command will do that by matching zero or more spaces at the beginning of each line and removing them.

```bsh
sed 's/^ *//' file
```

Using `cut` and `rev` is only possible if you know for a fact that you have no more spaces on any line than the initial ones and the single space between the number and the word, which you say nothing about. If you have a line saying `12 Abba Baab`, that no longer holds.