# read -r vs read -r line and IFS

Tags: bash

I've been revising the IFS stuff around here and there and could in no way explain the behaviour of different code snippets that boils down to this:

```
$ read -r < <(printf "%s\n" " x ")  && echo \<"$REPLY"\>
< x >
$ read -r line < <(printf "%s\n" " x ")  && echo \<"$line"\>
<x>
```

Of course `man bash` has it all.

> If no names are supplied, **the line read is assigned to the variable
>   REPLY**. The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered,
>   read  times  out  (in  which case the return code is greater than
>   128), a variable  assignment error (such as assigning to a readonly
>   variable) occurs, or an  invalid file descriptor is supplied as the
>   argument to -u.

I just thought it would be nice if one of those IFS-related answers contained a word on this *casus*. Some are even openly wrong, as it turns out. One example is the edit in this paragraph from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18923/181255):

> IFS is not used by read unless it is called with arguments. (**Edit**:
>   This is not exactly true: whitespace characters, i.e. space and tab,
>   present in IFS are always ignored at the beginning/end of the input
>   line. )

This is a rhetorical question with no question mark. But correct me if I'm wrong, etc.

Comment: It seems that zsh returns `<x>` in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal behavior, followed by all Bourne/POSIX shells (dash, ksh, pdksh, mksh, bash, zsh even when not in sh emulation mode, BusyBox sh, Bourne shell, …) is that `read -r line` strips leading and trailing whitespace characters. More generally, `read -r line` strips a leading separator which consists of an arbitrary number of whitespace characters from `IFS` and at most one non-whitespace character from `IFS`. At the end of the line, only whitespace characters can get stripped, because if the line ends with a non-whitespace separator character then it ends with an empty field. This is a special case of the more general case: the first variable gets the first field, the second variable gets the second field, etc., and if there are more fields than variables then the last variables gets the remainder of the line except the trailing whitespace.

Calling `read` with an implicit variable name is a ksh extension which bash and zsh imitate. In ksh (both ATT and pdksh/mksh) and in zsh, `read` without a variable name is exactly equivalent to `read` with the variable name `REPLY`. In bash, for some reason, the behavior is different: when the variable name is implicit, `IFS` whitespace strippping is not done. This is deliberate, but the rationale for making it different escapes me. (If you want no stripping, the standard method is to run `IFS= read -r`.)

```
  /* If there are no variables, save the text of the line read to the
     variable $REPLY.  ksh93 strips leading and trailing IFS whitespace,
     so that `read x ; echo "$x"' and `read ; echo "$REPLY"' behave the
     same way, but I believe that the difference in behaviors is useful
     enough to not do it.  Without the bash behavior, there is no way
     to read a line completely without interpretation or modification
     unless you mess with $IFS (e.g., setting it to the empty string).
     If you disagree, change the occurrences of `#if 0' to `#if 1' below. */
  if (list == 0)
    {
#if 0
      orig_input_string = input_string;
      for (t = input_string; ifs_chars && *ifs_chars && spctabnl(*t) && isifs(*t
        ;
      input_string = t;
      input_string = strip_trailing_ifs_whitespace (input_string, ifs_chars, saw
#endif
```