# Invert results for "for in * do"-loops

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reverse a for loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27382/how-do-i-reverse-a-for-loop)

Is there an easy way to invert a for in loop? For a script I want to process files in their reverse order.

So instead of:

```
for file in *.jpg;
  do echo $file;
done
```

with the result

```
001.jpg
002.jpg
003.jpg
...
150.jpg
```

I want the result

```
150.jpg
149.jpg
148.jpg
...
001.jpg
```

Comment: Ansgar Esztermann's solution will not work on the 'so called' *exact duplicate*, but on this example here, with numbers in filenames, which makes it a different thing. I vote to reopen.

Comment: @userunknown That's why I didn't merge them, but the duplicate is a more general case. Why would you want a more specific solution? It helps fewer people

Comment: The solutions are more easy. Shorter to type, easier to remember. I have an even shorter one and would gain magnitudes of reputation, if I could publish it! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
array=(*.jpg)
for ((i = ${#array[@]} - 1;i >= 0;i--)); do
    echo ${array[i]}
done
```

Answer (score 2):

In the given example, you could use

```
for num in `seq -w 150 -1 1`
  do echo $num.jpg
done
```

This is, of course, not totally equivalent, as it does not really invert the globbing, but instead generates the sequence externally.