# What is the fastest way to process line by line in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to loop over the lines of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file)

Let's say I `cat` a file and I want to run a bash command on each line and write each line as output.

How can I run a bash command on a single line the most succinct way?

```
cat something | lineBylineInplpace grep -E "spo" > &1
```

(I forget the standard descriptor symbol = / )

Should output the output of each line to the new file in place with the line it used for input.

I realize that this is very similar to awk. Is there a bash builtin kind of way to make this faster?

Comment: i found http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-shell-script-read-file-line-by-line-136784/page2.html

Comment: this seems to be the best so far cat file | 
(
while read line
do
echo process $line
done
)

Comment: You like useless uses of cats, don't you?

Comment: And see also [Understanding IFS](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26784)

Comment: i learned IFS the last time you recommended it =)

Comment: also its not a duplicate i wanted to edit line by line in the file this seems a bit pushy and negative to close this topic. there are a million ways to do things like this and i am sure there are ways that you dont kno this "bash" thing has been around for a while if u didnt know. the problem i think is people really forgot how they used it and i want to kno not get pushed down on the stack

Answer (score 11):

The proper way to process a file line by lines is :

```
   while read -r line; do
       echo "$line"
    done < /path/to/file.txt
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

**NOTE**

- using `unix pipes` have a cost, better avoid it for speed

Comment: hey thank you nice link that will help a small correction    echo "$line" should be    echo "$line" >> output  =)

Comment: Free free to modify it to fit your needs. =)

Comment: You missed setting `IFS`. See [How to loop over the lines of a file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7011) and other threads we've already had on this topic.