# Downloading files over ssh based on a list of filenames

Tags: files, ftp

So here is what I have done already:

I have a file called abc.txt which contains list of files. I am using abc.txt to
move those files to a folder, tar that folder and finally I download the tar to my local PC from my server, which is running GNU/Linux.

Here are the steps in list form:

1. abc.txt
2. abc.txt (listed files) -> folder
3. Folder -> folder.tar
4. folder.tar -> local PC.

If abc.txt contains 2 files, for example:

```
example1.css
example2.css
```

I need to download those files from abc.txt separately and directly to the local PC.

Since ftp or sftp need the file name to download it, how can I read that from abc.txt?

Comment: you download the file read it locally and redownload the right file ?

Comment: or you use ssh to execute the script on your remote machine.

Answer (score 5):

If the file `abc.txt` contains the list of filenames relative from `/path/to/base`:

```
ssh user@server tar c -T /path/to/abc.txt -C /path/to/base | (cd /tmp; tar xv)
```

This creates a tarball on-the-fly, without actually saving it anywhere, pipe it to the local shell, extract, effectively copying the listed files.

**EXTRA TIPS**

If the file `abc.txt` contains the list of absolute paths:

```
ssh user@server tar c -T /path/to/abc.txt | (cd /tmp; tar xv)
```

If the file `abc.txt` is on your local system, not the remote:

```
ssh user@server tar c -T- < /path/to/abc.txt | (cd /tmp; tar xv)
```

To use `gzip` compression (using default level 6):

```
ssh -C user@server tar c -T /path/to/abc.txt | (cd /tmp; tar xv)
```

To use `gzip` compression level 9:

```
ssh user@server 'tar c -T /path/to/abc.txt | gzip -9' | (cd /tmp; tar zxv)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple script witch works with files containing spaces in the filename :

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS; IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") ; for elt in `cat abc.txt` ; do scp $elt <YOUR_SFTP_CONNECTION> ; done ; IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Comment: Why treat backspace as a separator? (Yes, I know you read it somewhere, but I've never traced it back to its origin. It makes no sense.) You forgot to turn off globbing. Using `read` is more robust, see [How to loop over the lines of a file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7011).

Answer (score 0):

I think the hub of your problem is how to extract the correct files from your list for your subsequent two logic paths.

```
egrep 'example1.css|example2.css' abc.txt
```

will give you all lines that match the exceptions, and

```
egrep -v 'example1.css|example2.css' abc.txt
```

will give you all lines that don't match the exceptions