# Mount unionfs (or aufs) branches fed from stdin?

Tags: overlayfs, aufs, union-mount, unionfs

Is it possible to feed the branch paths from stdin to the mount (or mount_unionfs) command, instead of supplying them as arguments or from a file?

```
cat ~/dirs_with_photos.txt | mount -t unionfs
```

I don't want to use `/etc/fstab`, because ideally I want to automatically generate these txt files dynamically, such as with a cron job:

```
@weekly  find $HOME -type d -iname "*photos*" > ~/dirs_with_photos.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform the input into the required syntax and splice it into the command line with a [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution).

```
dirs_with_photos="$(<~/dirs_with_photos.txt tr '\n' :)"
if [ -n "$dirs_with_photos" ]; then
  unionfs-fuse "${dirs_with_photos%:}" /photos
fi
```

With [`mount_unionfs`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?mount_unionfs(8)) you need to issue one mount command per directory. You can use a [loop around the `read` builtin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file).

```
while IFS= read -r dir; do
  mount_unionfs "$dir" /photos
done <~/dirs_with_photos.txt
```