# Variable within path to file in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I've got a file, that contains about 20k strings. 
Each string in that file should be an argument for a command within bash script.

At first my script generates a file with this strings.

```
find /home/alotoffolders -type f -name  "*.mp4" | grep some_greps > ~/tests/find_smth
```

After that trying to set a variable, that will be a part of argument

```
filename=$(cut -d/ -f11 ~/tests/find_smth)
```

Then I'm trying to read all file line by line and use every string as an input argument (seems like it works), but for output - there is some issue.

```
  for i in `cat ~/tests/find_smth`; do ./other_script -input $i -output /home/folder1/folder2/$filename; done
```

Script can't see the static path before $filename.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

- [NEVER use](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file) `for i in $(cat ...) ...` or similar. It loops over words, not lines. And even if it would, filenames are allowed to contain newlines.
- Use [shell parameter expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash) or  `basename` command instead of `cut` to get the file name.
- Instead of using `grep` on the results of `find`, you might use e.g. `find`'s `-regex` or `-iregex` option.

---

Use `find -exec` with `sh -c`:

```
find /home/alotoffolders -type f -iregex 'some_pattern.mp4' \
  -exec sh -c '
    /path/to/other_script -input "$1" -output "/home/folder1/folder2/${1##*/}"
  ' find-sh {} \;
```