# bash: filter text stream by command result

Tags: bash, pipe, filter

Is there a standard tool that can filter text stream based on command execution result?

Consider `grep` for example. It can filter text stream based on regex. But the more general problem is extending filtering condition. For example, I may want to select all files matching some condition (`find` has plenty of checks available, but it is a subset anyway), or just use another program to filter my data. Consider this pipe:

```bsh
produce_data | xargs -l bash -c '[ -f $0 ] && ping -c1 -w1 $1 && echo $0 $@'
```

It is completely useless, but it provides a general approach. I can use any bash oneliner to test each line. In this example I want the lines which consist of existing file and a reachable host. I would like to have a standard tool that can do it like this:

```bsh
produce_data | super_filter -- bash -c '[ -f $0 ] && ping -c1 -w1 $1'
```

it could be easily used with `find`:

```bsh
find here | super_filter -- test -r
```

note how it allows you to use universal tools to filter files instead of specific `find` flags which I always forget.

A more real-life example where such tool would be helpful is finding object files with specific symbols.

So `super_filter` would allow any condition checker to operate in stream mode. The syntax could be like in `xargs` or `parallel`.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't GNU Parallel work if you add `&& echo`?

```
... | parallel 'test -r {} && echo {}'
```

Comment: nice solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## `while read` approach (pure bash)

`while read` is a common idiom to process input line by line ([How to loop over the lines of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file)). Do any checks and conditionally `echo` the original input line.

```bsh
... | while IFS= read -r line; do test -r "$line" && echo "$line"; done
```

## Special case: `find`

[Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice/321757#321757)

`find` have an `-exec` action to perform arbitrary actions and checks on found files:

From `man find`:

> ```
> -exec command ;
>    Execute  command;  true  if 0 status is returned.  All following arguments to
>    find are taken to be arguments to the command until an argument consisting of
>    `;' is encountered.  The string `{}' is replaced by the current file name be‐
>    ing processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not  just
>    in  arguments  where it is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both of these
>    constructions might need to be escaped (with a `\') or quoted to protect them
>    from  expansion  by  the shell.  See the EXAMPLES section for examples of the
>    use of the -exec option.  The specified command is run once for each  matched
>    file.  The command is executed in the starting directory.  There are unavoid‐
>    able security problems surrounding use of the -exec action;  you  should  use
>    the -execdir option instead.
> ```

Example:

```bsh
find here -exec test -r {} \; -print
```

Since `-exec` action overrides the default `-print` action, `-print` must be specified explicitly. This behavior is described in EXPRESSION section of find(1) man page. If you are going to apply further processing, use `-print0` + `xargs --null` instead of `-print`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out a solution that saves one process launch (with `while read`). I find it a little harder to read than `xargs` or `parallel`, but the latter spawn separate processes which can be unwanted sometimes.

Comment: Note, solutions that accept bash script as string argument (`xargs bash -c` and `parallel`) may require some extra work on quoting. E. g. `echo '$0 =' "$0"` should be written like
`bash -c "echo '\$0 =' \"\$0\""`.
With `while read` approach no extra level of quoting is required