# Extract info in loops from specific column based on list of input

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, text-formatting

I have fileA and fileB.

fileA is storing a list of names I wanted to extract from the second column of fileB.

fileA:

```
QW123
BH876
PR009
```

fileB:

```
MJ194   PR009   100
PR009   IJ940   78
JG948   BH448   58
```

desire output:

```
MJ194   PR009   100
JG948   BH448   58
```

I am trying it with the command below but none of them worked. Wondering what is left out in between the codes.

- `for i in $(cat fileA); do awk '$2=="$i"' fileB; done`
- `for i in $(cat fileA); do awk -v 'i="$i"' '$2=="i"' fileB; done`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second attempt would "work" if you remove extraneous quoting:

```
for i in $(cat fileA); do awk -v i="$i" '$2==i' fileB; done    # but don't do this
```

However, if you are determined to use a shell loop, it would be better to use `while`:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do awk -v i="$i" '$2==i' fileB; done < fileA    # don't do this either
```

Better would be to avoid the shell loop altogether:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $2 in a' fileA fileB
```

See also:

- [How to loop over the lines of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file)
- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Hi @steeldriver, thanks! The third options looked pretty neat. But wondering if it possible to print output files according to fileA strings? I used to do `>> $i.output` with for loops to get the output files (where `>> $i.output` will generate  `QW123.output`; `BH876.output` and `PR009.output`).

Comment: @web yes it is - for example `$2 in a {print > $2 ".output"}`

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any recommended open resources or reference book (probably) that I can learn more on writing codes as in the third option?

Comment: @web I usually reach for [The GNU Awk User’s Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#SEC_Contents) - just be aware that not all gawk features are supported by other awk implementations.