# How to iterate over matches which contain spaces

Tags: shell, quoting

I have a file that looks like this

```py
# ... stuff

@late()
def test1():
    # ...

@late()
def test2():
    # ...
```

I need to get each match **after** the `@late()` line and do some work on them.

I've tried getting the line after using `awk '/^@late()/{getline; print}' $the_file_path`. The results are correct but when I iterate over the matches

```bsh
for line in `awk '/^@late()/{getline; print}' $the_file_path`
do
    echo $line
done
```

I get

```
def
test1():
def
test2():
```

As you can see, the "def test1()" and "def test2()" are split at the " ".

Desired print output

```
def test1():
def test2():
```

I've tried surrounding each line in quotes to prevent it from breaking at the space but have had no luck. Can I get a pointer on how to handle this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to loop over the lines of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file). Read also: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Use process substitution like:  `while IFS= read -r line; do ... done < <(awk ...)`

Comment: What do you mean by "to do some work on them"? Do you want to change them or extract them? If you're extracting them, you can't really change them and then easily put them back in.

Comment: As noted by @Kusalananda, please edit your question to include the desired output so contributors can understand what you are trying to achieve.