# I don't really understand expansion and quoting on the shell (zsh/bash)

Tags: bash, zsh, for, split

I've read up on a few answers here in reference to quoting variables on the shell.
Basically, here's what I'm running:

`for f in "$(tmsu files)"; do echo "${f}"; done`

this has the expected outcome: a list of files. However, I'm pretty sure they're coming out as a single string. After some reading I realized that this is a zsh-ism; it deals with splitting differently than most shells.

So I fired up `bash` and ran the same command. I was expecting it to split the list, but alas, I got *exactly* the same result. So now I'm really confused.

1. Why doesn't bash behave as expected?
2. How do I get zsh to split lines?

I've tried (zsh):
`for f in "$(tmsu files)"; do echo "${=f}"; done`
as well as
`for f in "$(=tmsu files)"; do echo "${f}"; done`
neither worked, so obviously I'm mis-understanding how to get `zsh` to split.

What makes this even worse is at some point I had this doing exactly what I wanted it to, and I can't remember how I did that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quoting within $(command substitution) in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118433/quoting-within-command-substitution-in-bash)

Comment: `for f in ...` iterates over *words* (where "words" has a rather idiosyncratic definition). If you want to iterate over *lines*, [do not use a `for` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor); use a `while IFS= read -r ...` loop instead.

Comment: @GordonDavisson the link you posted is really helpful, thanks.

Comment: @Haxiel, no, it doesn't, because they want splitting along lines here, while that one focuses on _not_ splitting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I'm pretty sure they're coming out as a single string.

This is what you get when you use quotes. I can't speak to how `zsh` is supposed to do it, but the `bash` manual states as much (section "Word Splitting", under "EXPANSION"):

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion,  command  substitution,  and arithmetic expansion **that did not occur within double quotes** for word splitting.

(emphasis added). Note that word splitting also does not occur with single quotes; however, substitution and expansion does not occur within them either.

If you want separate arguments out of the command substitution, you need to remove the quotes. However, if `tmsu` produces any results with spaces, those will also yield undesirable splits (since both spaces and newlines are considered word delimiters), making things a little more complicated. In `bash`, assuming `tmsu` gives one result per line, you can do this:

```bsh
tmsu files |
    while IFS= read -r f
    do
        printf "<%s>\n" "$f"
    done
```

The `read` builtin reads a whole line of input. You can give it any number of names. All but the last are assigned based on the word delimiter (space by default), and the last is assigned the remainder of the line, so it's a good way to get around `bash`'s annoying treatment of whitespace in expansion and substitution.

Comment: Note: zsh and bash and sh all do this the same way.

Comment: Ugh. Everything I read basically said "use double quotes by default unless you understand what you're doing and have a good reason not to." so this adds to the confusion I have around the topic. I probably just need to learn how to use `read`. Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed response.

Comment: Don't feel too bad. Shell languages have really complicated semantics. I can't say I fully understand `bash` myself, and I have trouble around whitespace and parameter expansion quite often.

Comment: Right, that helps, thanks. And I think I have the syntax in a form that works although it'll take me a while to figure out how/why it works (and why it breaks in the ways it does).

Comment: _"Note that word splitting also does not occur with single quotes..."_ -- word splitting is completely irrelevant within single quotes, since it only happens for the results of expansions, and those don't happen within single quotes. (Consider something like `IFS=x; echoxhi`, even though it's not quoted, the word there isn't split since it's not a result of an expansion. (Unless you're in a really ancient pre-POSIX shell, IIRC))

Comment: Even with one argument `read` _still_ has annoying treatment of whitespace if `IFS` contains any. E.g. with the default `IFS` entering `␣foo␣bar` (spaces marked as `␣`) to `read x` produces `foo␣bar` in the variable, i.e. it loses the leading space... Also there's the treatment of backspaces, so you need `IFS= read -r ...` to get the data cleanly

Comment: @ilkkachu Right. Thanks for that.

Comment: It is possible to set IFS to a literal newline character, and only a literal newline character (I usually type it as `IFS=` followed by Ctrl+v Ctrl+j, the continuing with the `for...` ), at which point the `for` loop will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Also, zsh is great about always substituting variables as single arguments, even if they contain spaces. IOW, `IFS=<newline> for f in \`ls -1\`; do cp $f /tmp/; done` will copy all of the files in the current directory to `/tmp/`, even if some of the names have spaces in them. No extra quoting needed.

Answer (score 6):

```
for f in "$(tmsu files)"; do echo "${f}"; done
```

That's more like the wrong thing to do than a zsh-ism. The double-quotes tell the shell to keep the result of the expansion as a single string. In most cases that's what you want, e.g. if you have

```
filename="foo bar"
ls "$filename"
```

you want `ls` to get the filename as a single argument, and not as the two arguments `foo` and `bar`. (Those would be different filenames.) Now, the fact that you're using a command substitution there doesn't change that. Though you're right in that quoting doesn't solve your problem in this case, but that construct is awkward to begin with. (In a POSIX shell that is, zsh has tools of its own, of course).

Consider a list of files like:

```
hello.txt
some silly name with spaces.txt
```

Using `"$(output filenames)"` would give you that as one string, not two.
Using `$(output filenames)` would give you that as six strings, not two.

You could solve that by setting `IFS` to just the newline, so the latter would split on the newlines and give you the two filenames. But it's a nuisance, has a global effect, and you still need to disable globbing with `set -f` too in case the file name is `funny * name.txt` instead.

(This far it's still mostly the same with zsh, since it does split the results of an unquoted command substitution, even if it doesn't split a variable expansion. It doesn't do globbing on the result by default though.)

Now, the reason you can't see the difference is that `echo` prints all the arguments it gets, joined with single spaces. So `echo foo bar` and `echo "foo bar"` produce exactly the same output. Instead, use something like `printf "<%s>\n" ...`, which lets you see the argument borders more clearly:

```
$ printf "<%s>\n" foo bar
<foo>
<bar>
$ printf "<%s>\n" "foo bar"
<foo bar>
```

See also:

- [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) on Greg's wiki
- [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)
- [How to loop over the lines of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7011/170373) (it says "lines of a file", but it doesn't matter if you have `cat` or whatever inside the command substitution), and as always:
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Answer (score 4):

> 2. How do I get zsh to split lines?

With the `f` parameter expansion flag (details in `man zshexpn`. It says: Split the result of the expansion at newlines. This is a shorthand for `ps:\n:`.)

```
for f in ${(f)"$( tmsu files )"}; do
  print -ru2 -- $f
done
```

Sending output to stderr to leave stdout for printing pipeable data to (presumably there is more happening than just printing the output).

If your tool can produce output delimited by the ascii null character (aka NUL, \0), then zsh can split that output using the `0` flag (shorthand for `ps:\0:`) instead of `f`.

To preserve blank records, add the `@` flag and `"` quotes (e.g. `"${(@f)"$( command )"}"`). Due to the nature of command substitution, it won't be possible to retrieve trailing newlines.

If you feel like using `read` in a `while` loop, something like the following should work in either zsh or bash:

```
while IFS= read -ru3 -d '' x || [[ $x ]]; do
  {
    printf >&2 '%s\n' "$x"
    z=$x
  } 3<&-
done 3< <(printf 'x\0y\0z')
printf 'z: %s\n' "$z"
```

No field splitting or backslash interpretation, the loop is not run in a subshell, stdin is still available, and last element is found despite the lack of a trailing delimiter.

Comment: Beware `${(f)"$(cmd)"}` removes the empty lines though, so it's not the same thing as looping over the line with `while IFS= read -r`.