# loop through file by row in tcsh

Tags: tcsh

This is a very similar question to [How to loop over the lines of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/how-to-loop-over-the-lines-of-a-file).

I have a file with rows with *n* fields, separated by spaces. I want to loop through this file by row, and use the set the fields as variables, for use in calling information from a different file.

So, for example, my file looks like this:

```
A B C
D E F
H I J
K L M
```

I'd like to loop thru each line and set the variables to be the fields:

```
foreach i ( `cat file ` )
set 1st = $i[1]; set 2nd = $i[2]; set 3rd = $i[3]
end
```

Right now, my shell is using spaces to separate the fields, and this means I can't set the 3 variables in each row.

Were I to `echo` each `$i` - I'd see this:

```
A
B
C
D
....
```

I'd like to know how to control my loop by using only the new lines as the separators.

Here's what I really want to achieve.
I want to grep rows in file A which contain 3 different values, all of which appear as space separated elements in the rows of file B. My plan was to loop thru each line in file B, setting variables for each of the (space separated) elements in that row of B, and then make use of these 3 elements. And then repeat for the next row of B. But my loop fails because it doesn't see the rows in file B. It only sees ALL the space separated elements, with no recognition of their grouping into rows of 3 elements. I hope this isn't confusing

Comment: Please read [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) for why processing files with shells is a bad idea and see [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) for why it is a particularly bad idea to use csh-style shells for programming.

Comment: don't have much option re csh unfortunately, just looking for a solution

Comment: You mean you are on a system that doesn't have `sh` installed and doesn't have the basic text processing tools like per, awk, sed etc? What operating system are you using?

Comment: no, I meant I am limited to using tcsh.  I can certainly use sh, awk, sed.  How would I do that here?

Comment: What is the final objective here? Do you just want to print the lines to the terminal? Do you need to do some downstream processing? The usual solution is to just do whatever you want to do in `awk` or `perl` or `sed` or any other tool more suitable to text parsing. If you [edit] your question and explain what the final objective is, we should be able to help.

Comment: I wanted to set each field in each row (so in row 1 - set 1st = A , set 2nd =B, set 3rd = C) to create variables, work with those variables to obtain a result inside the file

Comment: Yes, but again, no shell is a good option for this and tcsh is a particularly bad option. This is what is known as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). I suggest you [edit] your question, show us an actual example of the data and explain what  result you need to get. That way, we can give you a solution that won't require using the shell.

Comment: ``foreach i ( `cat file ` )`` unrolls all the values as separate items, as each one is separated from the next by some form of whitespace. Right there, you've lost any representation of _n_ fields per line

Comment: "_I am limited to using `tcsh`_" - but [you then say](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678487/loop-through-file-by-row-in-tcsh#comment1281547_678487) "_I can certainly use `sh`_. So you're not limited to `tcsh` and you can use a shell that's got decent flow control loops. Remember that your interactive shell need not be the one that runs shell scripts

Comment: @roaima I didn't have success running it as a shell script either.  How do control the loop so it treats each row as complete unit to be worked on?

Comment: You don't. Instead, use a tool that reads _and processes_ the data directly. If you care to tell us what you're trying to achieve them someone here may well be able to help you

Comment: I want to grep rows in file A which contain 3 different values, all of which appear as space separated elements in the rows of file B.  My plan was to loop thru each line in file B, setting variables for each of the (space separated) elements in that row of B, and then make use of these 3 elements.  And then repeat for the next row of B.  But my loop fails because it doesn't see the rows in file B.  It only sees ALL the space separated elements, with no recognition of their grouping into rows of 3 elements.  I hope this isn't confusing.

Comment: Is the example file your A or your B? Do you have a matching example of the other file you can add to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the original problem was communicated clearly enough, but it seems that I have a problem in my shell environment looping thru rows of a text file where the rows have space separated elements, such as, for example

```
row 1: A B C
row 2: D E F
```

I've found a workaround for this by converting each row into one element, in a way I can parse it later for uses beyond (I think) the scope of this question .  So my two rows above become

```
row 1: A_B_C
row 2: D_E_F
```

in such a format, my foreach loop sees each row as a single element and if I now need B in my first iteration, I can use, for example:

```
foreach i ( `cat <file>` )
foreach? set a = `echo $i | awk -F '_' '{print($2)}'`
foreach? echo $a
foreach? end
```

This should echo:

```
B
E
```

which would be the 2nd element in each row of my file

Thanks to everyone who took an interest and if there is a more elegant way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Write the whole thing in awk.   or perl. or almost any language that isn't sh/bash/ksh/zsh/etc or csh/tcsh. The big mistake you are making is trying to do text processing in csh (and it wouldn't be much better in a bourne-like shell - less buggy, but still awful).   If you want to do text processing, then use a language suited to it, like awk or perl.  Shells are good at setting up pipes and feeding data into other programs that do data processing.  They are terrible at doing data processing themselves.

Comment: A sh or csh script's role in any non-trivial data processing task is to be a wrapper around other programs - grep, awk, sed, perl, and many others - that do the actual work.  shells do the setup, other programs do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I wish some people would just answer the question. Is it possible? Yes. Is it recommended? No. But if you HAVE to you can do it by following the answer of this stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926372/how-to-iterate-every-line-from-variable-on-the-basis-of-new-line-character-inste

Comment: Instead of posting an answer, you should flag the question as a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @DanielWalker you can't flag a duplicate on a different stackexchange site

Comment: @ChrisDavies, ah, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Word splitting is something csh almost got better than the Bourne shell. In csh, `` "`cmd`" `` splits the output of `cmd` into its non-empty lines not doing globbing while `` `cmd` `` splits on space tab or newline and does globbing. So you could do:

```
set n = 0 noglob
foreach line ( "`cat file`" )
  @ n++
  set field = ( $line )
  echo First field of line $n is $field[1], second is $field[2]
end
```

Though of course to do text processing by lines and fields, you'd use something like `perl` or `awk`, not a shell loop.